# Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

In **C++**, is there any difference between:

```
struct Foo { ... };
```

and:

```
typedef struct { ... } Foo;
```

Comment: Related question and answer: [difference between using and typedef in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11)

Comment: See also [the related question about C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)

Answer (score 1381, accepted):

In C++, there is only a subtle difference.  It's a holdover from C, in which it makes a difference.

The C language standard ([C89 §3.1.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.txt), [C99 §6.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.3), and [C11 §6.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3)) mandates separate namespaces for different categories of identifiers, including *tag identifiers* (for `struct`/`union`/`enum`) and *ordinary identifiers* (for `typedef` and other identifiers).

If you just said:

```
struct Foo { ... };
Foo x;
```

you would get a compiler error, because `Foo` is only defined in the tag namespace.

You'd have to declare it as:

```
struct Foo x;
```

Any time you want to refer to a `Foo`, you'd always have to call it a `struct Foo`.  This gets annoying fast, so you can add a `typedef`:

```
struct Foo { ... };
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```

Now `struct Foo` (in the tag namespace) and just plain `Foo` (in the ordinary identifier namespace) both refer to the same thing, and you can freely declare objects of type `Foo` without the `struct` keyword.

---

The construct:

```
typedef struct Foo { ... } Foo;
```

is just an abbreviation for the declaration and `typedef`.

---

Finally,

```
typedef struct { ... } Foo;
```

declares an anonymous structure and creates a `typedef` for it.  Thus, with this construct, it doesn't have a name in the tag namespace, only a name in the typedef namespace.  This means it also cannot be forward-declared.  *If you want to make a forward declaration, you have to give it a name in the tag namespace*.

---

In C++, all `struct`/`union`/`enum`/`class` declarations act like they are implicitly `typedef`'ed, as long as the name is not hidden by another declaration with the same name.  See [Michael Burr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c/612476#612476) for the full details.

Comment: While what you say is true, AFAIK, the statement, 'typedef struct { ... } Foo;' creates an alias for an unnamed struct.

Comment: Good catch, there's a subtle difference between "typedef struct Foo { ... } Foo;" and "typedef struct { ... } Foo;".

Comment: In C, the struct tags, union tags and enumeration tags share one namespace, rather than (struct and union) using two as claimed above; the namespace referenced for typedef names is indeed separate.  That means you can't have both 'union x { ... };' and 'struct x { ... };' in a single scope.

Comment: Aside from the not-quite-typedef thing, another difference between the two pieces of code in the question is that Foo can define a constructor in the first example, but not in the second (since anonymous classes can't define constructors or destructors).

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: `"In C++, there is no difference"`, is it because there are no separate tag and typedef namespaces in C++?

Comment: @Lazer: There *are* subtle differences, but Adam means (as he goes on to say) that you can use 'Type var' to declare variables without a typedef.

Comment: Can you please say what is `tag namespace` and where it start and ends?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I quoted part of your explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072718/errors-while-trying-to-pass-a-structure-to-a-function/13072758#13072758). You deserve the credit. Great answer!

Comment: IIRC I had some troubles using anonymous structs as template arguments. So, if one wants to write a header that is meant for C as well as C++ compilers, where you use the types as template arguments in C++, the struct should have a name.

Comment: What about `typedef struct Foo {...}`? I've just come across this declaration [here](http://256.com/sources/skip/docs/skipLists.c) (`typedef struct nodeStructure`). It seems to me that `typedef` here has no use, as later in the code `nodeStructure` is used with `struct` keyword.

Comment: I am a bit confused after reading all the posts regarding this question. Could you explain some of my questions [here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386191/typedef-name-conflicts-with-struct-tag-in-c) I am sure Ben is correct. I am just trying to get more inputs here. Thanks!

Comment: How to predefine struct with typedef WITHOUT declaring it? I want just `typedef struct Foo` and later on in the code I'll write `struct Foo {...}`.

Comment: Does this difference between "namespaces" in C and C++ (implicit typedef) creates a backwards incompatibility between C++ and C?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: the tag namespace is the list of tags used with `struct tag` or `union tag` or `enum tag`.  The namespace starts at the beginning of the translation unit (TU) and ends at the end of the TU.  It is scoped so declarations inside `{ … }` override declarations outside.

Comment: ok , for a `typedef struct _Foo_ { float x} Foo;` i.e can tag and ordinary namscape have different names or the underscore doesn't matter?

Comment: Hey @AdamRosenfield , I don't quite understand what you mean by the `tag` namespace and the `identifier` space, thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are *tag identifiers* and *ordinary identifiers*? Also, what is *tag namespace*?

Answer (score 253):

In [this DDJ article](http://drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=184403396), Dan Saks explains one small area where bugs can creep through if you do not typedef your structs (and classes!):

> If you want, you can imagine that C++
>   generates a typedef for every tag
>   name, such as
>
> ```
> typedef class string string;
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, this is not entirely
>   accurate. I wish it were that simple,
>   but it's not. C++ can't generate such
>   typedefs for structs, unions, or enums
>   without introducing incompatibilities
>   with C.
>
> For example, suppose a C program
>   declares both a function and a struct
>   named status:
>
> ```
> int status(); struct status;
> ```
>
> Again, this may be bad practice, but
>   it is C. In this program, status (by
>   itself) refers to the function; struct
>   status refers to the type.
>
> If C++ did automatically generate
>   typedefs for tags, then when you
>   compiled this program as C++, the
>   compiler would generate:
>
> ```
> typedef struct status status;
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, this type name would
>   conflict with the function name, and
>   the program would not compile. That's
>   why C++ can't simply generate a
>   typedef for each tag.
>
> In C++, tags act just like typedef
>   names, except that a program can
>   declare an object, function, or
>   enumerator with the same name and the
>   same scope as a tag. In that case, the
>   object, function, or enumerator name
>   hides the tag name. The program can
>   refer to the tag name only by using
>   the keyword class, struct, union, or
>   enum (as appropriate) in front of the
>   tag name. A type name consisting of
>   one of these keywords followed by a
>   tag is an elaborated-type-specifier.
>   For instance, struct status and enum
>   month are elaborated-type-specifiers.
>
> Thus, a C program that contains both:
>
> ```
> int status(); struct status;
> ```
>
> behaves the same when compiled as C++.
>   The name status alone refers to the
>   function. The program can refer to the
>   type only by using the
>   elaborated-type-specifier struct
>   status.
>
> So how does this allow bugs to creep
>   into programs? Consider the program in
>   [Listing 1](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403396?pgno=1). This program defines a
>   class foo with a default constructor,
>   and a conversion operator that
>   converts a foo object to char const *.
>   The expression
>
> ```
> p = foo();
> ```
>
> in main should construct a foo object
>   and apply the conversion operator. The
>   subsequent output statement
>
> ```
> cout << p << '\n';
> ```
>
> should display class foo, but it
>   doesn't. It displays function foo.
>
> This surprising result occurs because
>   the program includes header lib.h
>   shown in [Listing 2](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403396?pgno=2). This header
>   defines a function also named foo. The
>   function name foo hides the class name
>   foo, so the reference to foo in main
>   refers to the function, not the class.
>   main can refer to the class only by
>   using an elaborated-type-specifier, as
>   in
>
> ```
> p = class foo();
> ```
>
> The way to avoid such confusion
>   throughout the program is to add the
>   following typedef for the class name
>   foo:
>
> ```
> typedef class foo foo;
> ```
>
> immediately before or after the class
>   definition. This typedef causes a
>   conflict between the type name foo and
>   the function name foo (from the
>   library) that will trigger a
>   compile-time error.
>
> I know of no one who actually writes
>   these typedefs as a matter of course.
>   It requires a lot of discipline. Since
>   the incidence of errors such as the
>   one in [Listing 1](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403396?pgno=1) is probably pretty
>   small, you many never run afoul of
>   this problem. But if an error in your
>   software might cause bodily injury,
>   then you should write the typedefs no
>   matter how unlikely the error.
>
> I can't imagine why anyone would ever
>   want to hide a class name with a
>   function or object name in the same
>   scope as the class. The hiding rules
>   in C were a mistake, and they should
>   not have been extended to classes in
>   C++. Indeed, you can correct the
>   mistake, but it requires extra
>   programming discipline and effort that
>   should not be necessary.

Comment: In case you try "class foo()" and it fails: In ISO C++, "class foo()" is an illegal construct (the article was written '97, before standardization, it seems). You can put "typedef class foo foo;" into main, then you can say "foo();" (because then, the typedef-name is lexically closer than the function's name). Syntactically, in T(), T must be a simple-type-specifier. elaborated type specifiers are not allowed. Still this is a good answer, of course.

Comment: `Listing 1` and `Listing 2` links are broken. Have a look.

Comment: If you use different naming conventions for classes and functions, you also avoid the naming conflict without needing to add extra typedefs.

Answer (score 71):

One more important difference: `typedef`s cannot be forward declared. So for the `typedef` option you must `#include` the file containing the `typedef`, meaning everything that `#include`s your `.h` also includes that file whether it directly needs it or not, and so on. It can definitely impact your build times on larger projects.

Without the `typedef`, in some cases you can just add a forward declaration of `struct Foo;` at the top of your `.h` file, and only `#include` the struct definition in your `.cpp` file.

Comment: Why does exposing the definition of struct impact the build time? Does the compiler do extra checking even if it needs not to (given the typedef option, so that the compiler knows the definition) when it sees something like __Foo* nextFoo;__?

Comment: Its not really extra checking, its just more code that the compiler needs to deal with. For every cpp file that encounters that typedef somewhere in its include chain, its compiling the typedef. In larger projects the .h file containing the typedef could easily end up being compiled hundreds of times, although precompiled headers helps a lot. If you can get away with using a forward declaration, then its easier to limit inclusion of the .h containing the full struct specification to only the code that really cares, and therefore the corresponding include file is compiled less often.

Comment: please @ the previous commenter(other than the owner of the post). I almost missed ur reply. But thanks for the info.

Comment: This is not true anymore in C11, where can you can typedef the same struct with the same name several times.

Comment: @Joe: Another issue historically has been that when using `struct tagName` syntax, one can have two header files each contain a function that accepts a pointer to a struct defined in the other, while having one one definition of each struct between them.

Answer (score 35):

There **is** a difference, but subtle. Look at it this way: `struct Foo` introduces a new type. The second one creates an alias called Foo (and not a new type) for an unnamed `struct` type.

> **7.1.3 The typedef specifier**
>
> 1 [...]
>
> A name declared with the typedef specifier becomes a typedef-name. Within the scope of its declaration, a
>   typedef-name is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the identifier in
>   the way described in Clause 8. A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type. A typedef-name ***does not introduce a new type*** the way a class declaration (9.1) or enum declaration does.
>
> 8 If the typedef declaration defines an unnamed class (or enum), the first typedef-name declared by the declaration
>   to be that class type (or enum type) is used to denote the class type (or enum type) for linkage
>   purposes only (3.5). [ Example:

```
typedef struct { } *ps, S; // S is the class name for linkage purposes
```

So, a typedef **always** is used as an placeholder/synonym for another type.

Answer (score 10):

You can't use forward declaration with the typedef struct.

The struct itself is an anonymous type, so you don't have an actual name to forward declare.

```
typedef struct{
    int one;
    int two;
}myStruct;
```

A forward declaration like this wont work:

```
struct myStruct; //forward declaration fails

void blah(myStruct* pStruct);

//error C2371: 'myStruct' : redefinition; different basic types
```

Comment: I don't get the second error for the function prototype. Why does it say "redefinition; different basic types"? the compiler does not need to know what myStruct's definition looks like, right? No matter taken from with piece of code (the typedef one, or the forward declaration one), myStruct denotes a struct type, right?

Comment: @Rich It's complaining that there is a conflict of names. There's a forward declaration saying "look for a struct called myStruct" and then there's the typedef which is renaming a nameless structure as "myStruct".

Comment: You mean put both typedef and forward declaration in the same file? I did, and gcc compiled it fine. myStruct is correctly interpreted as the nameless structure. Tag `myStruct` lives in tag namespace and typedef_ed `myStruct` lives in the normal namespace where other identifiers like function name, local variable names live in. So there should not be any conflict..I can show you my code if you doubt there is any error in it.

Comment: @Rich GCC gives the same error, text varies a bit: http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22FAFwngDgpgJlBmACAziATgVwMYkQb2ESMQEsA7XAezKgG5DjzcQB3S%2BgXwFswBldbCHrBUmHIh78xQ4MCYSAhuQAUASmAFiEvgPEL6xBojRQQGNGUQAGTkAA%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fclang%2B%2B%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O2%22%7D%5D%7D

Comment: I think I understand that when you only have a `typedef`, forward declaration with the `typedef`ed name, does not refer to the unnamed structure. Instead the forward declaration declares an incomplete structure with tag `myStruct`. Also, without seeing the definition of `typedef`, the function prototype using the `typedef`ed name is not legal. Thus we have to include the whole typedef whenever we need to use `myStruct` to denote a type. Correct me if I misunderstood u. Thanks.

Comment: I think ur code is compiled with g++ instead of gcc. In C++, this is definitely not allowed. As in C++, structure name is implicitly typedefed. But if you try gcc, it compiles fine.

Answer (score 3):

An important difference between a 'typedef struct' and a 'struct' in C++ is that inline member initialisation in 'typedef structs' will not work.

```
// the 'x' in this struct will NOT be initialised to zero
typedef struct { int x = 0; } Foo;

// the 'x' in this struct WILL be initialised to zero
struct Foo { int x = 0; };
```

Comment: **Not true. In both cases `x` is initialized.**  See [test in the Coliru online IDE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46c819ed3fbcf6d8) (I initialized it to 42 so it's more obvious than with zero that the assignment has really taken place).

Comment: Actually, I tested it in Visual Studio 2013 and it was not initialized. This was a problem we came across in production code. All compilers are different and only have to meet certain criteria.

Answer (score -3):

There is no difference in C++, but I believe in C it would allow you to declare instances of the struct Foo without explicitly doing:

```
struct Foo bar;
```

Comment: Look at @dirkgently's answer---there **is** a difference, but it's subtle.

Answer (score -6):

Struct is to create a data type.
The typedef is to set a nickname for a data type.

Comment: You did not understand the question.