# What does double underscore ( __const) mean in C?

Tags: c, syntax, double-underscore

```
extern int ether_hostton (__const char *__hostname, struct ether_addr *__addr)
 __THROW;
```

I found the above function definition in /usr/include/netinet/ether.h on a Linux box.

Can someone explain what the double underscores mean in front of const (keyword), addr (identifier) and at last __THROW.

Comment: There's a very, very good summary of the rules for reserved identifiers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Comment: Technically, the x-ref is 'reserved identifiers for C++', but there is (now) good information from the C standard too.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In C, symbols starting with an underscore followed by either an upper-case letter or another underscore are reserved for the implementation.  You as a user of C should not create any symbols that start with the reserved sequences.  In C++, the restriction is more stringent; you the user may not create a symbol containing a double-underscore.

Given:

```
extern int ether_hostton (__const char *__hostname, struct ether_addr *__addr)
__THROW;
```

The `__const` notation is there to allow for the possibility (somewhat unlikely) that a compiler that this code is used with supports prototype notations but does not have a correct understanding of the C89 standard keyword `const`.  The `autoconf` macros can still check whether the compiler has working support for `const`; this code could be used with a broken compiler that does not have that support.

The use of `__hostname` and `__addr` is a protection measure for you, the user of the header.  If you compile with GCC and the `-Wshadow` option, the compiler will warn you when any local variables shadow a global variable.  If the function used just `hostname` instead of `__hostname`, and if you had a function called `hostname()`, there'd be a shadowing.  By using names reserved to the implementation, there is no conflict with your legitimate code.

The use of `__THROW` means that the code can, under some circumstances, be declared with some sort of 'throw specification'.  This is not standard C; it is more like C++.  But the code can be used with a C compiler as long as one of the headers (or the compiler itself) defines `__THROW` to empty, or to some compiler-specific extension of the standard C syntax.

---

Section 7.1.3 of the C standard (ISO 9899:1999) says:

> #### 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers
>
> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and
>   optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions
>   subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file
>   scope identifiers.
>
> — All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>   underscore are always reserved for any use.
>
> — All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
>   with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.
>
> — Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the future library
>   directions) is reserved for use as specified if any of its associated headers is included;
>   unless explicitly stated otherwise (see 7.1.4).
>
> — All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the
>   future library directions) are always reserved for use as identifiers with external
>   linkage.<sup>154)</sup>
>
> — Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the
>   future library directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with
>   file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.
>
> No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
>   context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
>   identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.
>
> If the program removes (with `#undef`) any macro definition of an identifier in the first
>   group listed above, the behavior is undefined.
>
> Footnote 154) The list of reserved identifiers with external linkage includes `errno`, `math_errhandling`,
>   `setjmp`, and `va_end`.

---

See also [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797); a lot of the same rules apply to both C and C++, though the embedded double-underscore rule is in C++ only, as mentioned at the top of this answer.

---

### C99 Rationale

The [C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) says:

> **7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**
>
> To give implementors maximum latitude in packing library functions into files, all external
>   identifiers defined by the library are reserved in a hosted environment. This means, in effect, that no user-supplied external names may match library names, *not even if the user function has
>   the same specification.* Thus, for instance, `strtod` may be defined in the same object module as `printf`, with no fear that link-time conflicts will occur. Equally, `strtod` may call `printf`, or `printf` may call `strtod`, for whatever reason, with no fear that the wrong function will be called.
>
> Also reserved for the implementor are *all* external identifiers beginning with an underscore, and all other identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter or an underscore. This gives a name space for writing the numerous behind-the-scenes non-external macros and functions a library needs to do its job properly.
>
> With these exceptions, the Standard assures the programmer that *all other* identifiers are available, with no fear of unexpected collisions when moving programs from one
>   implementation to another<sup>5</sup>. Note, in particular, that part of the name space of internal identifiers beginning with underscore is available to the user: translator implementors have not been the only ones to find use for “hidden” names. C is such a portable language in many respects that the issue of “name space pollution” has been and is one of the principal barriers to writing completely portable code. Therefore the Standard assures that macro and `typedef` names are reserved only if the associated header is explicitly included.
>
> <sup>5</sup> See §6.2.1 for a discussion of some of the precautions an implementor should take to keep this promise. Note also that any implementation-defined member names in structures defined in `<time.h>` and `<locale.h>` must begin with an underscore, rather than following the pattern of other names in those structures.

And the relevant part of the rationale for **§6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers** is:

> Although the scope of an identifier in a function prototype begins at its declaration and ends at the end of that function’s declarator, this scope is ignored by the preprocessor. Thus an identifier
>   in a prototype having the same name as that of an existing macro is treated as an invocation of that macro. For example:
>
> ```
>     #define status 23
>     void exit(int status);
> ```
>
> generates an error, since the prototype after preprocessing becomes
>
> ```
>    void exit(int 23);
> ```
>
> Perhaps more surprising is what happens if status is defined
>
> ```
>    #define status []
> ```
>
> Then the resulting prototype is
>
> ```
>    void exit(int []);
> ```
>
> which is syntactically correct but semantically quite different from the intent.
>
> To protect an implementation’s header prototypes from such misinterpretation, the implementor must write them to avoid these surprises. Possible solutions include not using identifiers in prototypes, or using names in the reserved name space (such as `__status` or `_Status`).

See also P J Plauger [The Standard C Library](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0131315099) (1992) for an extensive discussion of name space rules and library implementations.  The book refers to C90 rather than any later version of the standard, but most of the implementation advice in it remains valid to this day.

Answer (score 19):

Names with double leading underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. This does not necessarily mean they are internal per se, although they often are.

The idea is, you're not allowed to to use any names starting with `__`, so the implementation is free to use them in places like macro expansions, or in the names of syntax extensions (e.g. `__gcnew` is not part of C++, but Microsoft can add it to C++/CLI confident that no existing code should have something like `int __gcnew;` in it that would stop compiling).

To find out what these specific extensions mean, i.e. `__const` you'll need to consult the documentation for your specific compiler/platform. In this particular case, you should probably consider the prototype in the documentation (e.g. http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/ether_aton.3.html) to be the function's interface and ignore the `__const` and `__THROW` decorations that appear in the actual header.

Comment: Thanks for the link..that definitely helps.

Answer (score 3):

By convention in some libraries, this indicates that a particular symbol is for internal use and not intended to be part of the public API of the library.

Comment: @Rob..So does that mean for programming purposes i can consider the function definition
extern int ether_hostton (__const char *__hostname, struct ether_addr *__addr)
     __THROW;

to be without underscores and __THROW.?

Comment: Maybe those are macros, and are for C++ compatibility? If you are compiling in C++ mode, `__THROW` == `throw()` and if const is supported then `__const` == `const`, or something along that?

Comment: @Deepak: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Rob if they are intended for internal use, could i ignore the underscores and just define variables of the desired type and access the values during function calls.

I just wanted to know if the underscore made any difference to the programmer who is using the API.

Comment: @Deepak: as far as you are concerned, the function returns an `int` and takes a string (`char *`) and a `struct ether_addr` pointer.  It doesn't matter what sort of string you pass as the name - the function won't modify it.  That's all you really need to know.  If you were writing the function, you'd have to worry about the semantics of `__const`.  The `__THROW` bit is meaningless in C unless there is either `#define __THROW /* Nothing */` or a compiler-specific extension is used; you don't have to worry about it, therefore.

Comment: @Jonathan..Thanks a million. That clarifies some concepts.

Answer (score 2):

The underscore in __const means that this keyword is a compiler extension and using it is not portable (The const keyword was added to C in a later revision, 89 I think).
The __THROW is also some kind of extension, I assume that it gets defined to some __attribute__(something) if gcc is used, But I'm not sure on that and too lazy to check.
The __addr can mean anything the programmer wanted it to mean, It's just a name.

Comment: So, from a user's perspective..if i just defined char *hostnameval, i could access the __const char* __hostname value?

Comment: Ok, I don't think I understand what you want to ask in that comment. The \__conts tells you, just like const, that the function will not change the value of \__hostname. For calling that function, the name \__hostname makes no difference to hostname or any other possible name.

Comment: @Caotic...i meant

if ether_hostton (__const char *__hostname, struct ether_addr *__addr) is just as good as ether_hostton (const char *(hostname/anyname), struct ether_addr *addr) as far as a user is c oncerned ?

Comment: Yes, there should be no differences