# Is there any difference between __typeof and typeof?

Tags: c++, c

There are more operators that work when we add __ to them too.
what does __ mean?

Comment: typeof is not a function, it is an operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does double underscore ( __const) mean in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449181/what-does-double-underscore-const-mean-in-c).

Comment: @WTP: That depends on how it is defined. It's just an identifier, it has no special meaning in C++ so it could be "#defined" to an operator or declared as a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An identifier with double underscores is reserved for the implementation. `typeof` is a compiler specific extension to the language, so naming it `__typeof` ensures no user code has an identifier with the same name

Comment: so why both typeof and __typeof are defined?

Comment: @user913461: I believe gcc has an option to disable the former, but not the later.  So if you have a file that uses `typeof` as an identifier, you can still get it to compile by disabling the `typeof` operator, but leaving the `__typeof` operator alone.

Comment: The double-underscore version is needed for compilers running in extremely strict standard compliance modes (like `gcc` with the `-ansi` or `-std` option).  When running with all of the normal gcc extensions enabled, the underscore-free version is available.  You will often see this on identifiers that are either compiler extensions or not available in every version of the language standard (`inline` is another example).