# Difference between typeof, __typeof and __typeof__ in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C I often use `__typeof__(obj)` when dealing with blocks etc. Why not `__typeof(obj)` or `typeof(obj)`.

When to use which?

Comment: I know someone else asked a similar question, but it unfortunately didn't cover all three. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618873/is-there-any-difference-between-typeof-and-typeof and was for c++

Comment: Hmm. I've always used constructs like `[obj isKindOf:otherObj]`.

Comment: Sorry, yes. isKindOfClass is something else.

Comment: `-isKindOfClass:` is a runtime check on the class of an object. The `typeof()` family is a compile-time check on the type (not just class) of any valid C expression.

Comment: Can we delete these off topic comments? I delete mine.

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#c-language-features explains `typeof`, `__typeof` and `__typeof__`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`__typeof__()` and `__typeof()` are compiler-specific extensions to the C language, because standard C does not include such an operator. Standard C requires compilers to prefix language extensions with a double-underscore (which is also why you should never do so for your own functions, variables, etc.)

`typeof()` is exactly the same, but throws the underscores out the window with the understanding that every modern compiler supports it. (Actually, now that I think about it, Visual C++ might not. It does support `decltype()` though, which generally provides the same behaviour as `typeof()`.)

All three mean the same thing, but none are standard C so a conforming compiler may choose to make any mean something different.

Comment: The sentence "If you are writing a header file that must work when included in ISO C programs, write `__typeof__` instead of `typeof`" on the following page seems to imply some sort of "standard" here though: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

Comment: Yes, in that non-standard extensions to the language should be prefixed with `__` to mark them as non-standard. `typeof()` is technically *bad* C, not just *nonstandard* C.

Comment: OK nice one.  I've never had any cause to use this feature in the 20-odd years of C programming I've done.  I'm not about to start now ;-)

Comment: So what's the difference between `__typeof()` and `__typeof__()`?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 33):

As others have mentioned, `typeof()` is an extension of **C** that has various support in respective compilers.
If you happen to be writing Objective-C for iOS or Mac apps, chances are good that you will be compiling your app with the **Clang** compiler.

Clang does support the use of `typeof()`, but technically it's for when your C Language Dialect is set to be a **gnu*** type. However `__typeof__()` is supported in both **c*** and **gnu*** language dialects - as detailed in the Clang [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#differences-between-various-standard-modes).

Now if you're writing your code with Xcode, the default setting for the C language dialect appears to be GNU99 and the option of allowing **'asm' 'inline' 'typeof'** is set to **Yes**, so using `typeof()` won't bring you any problems.

[image: Xcode project settings]

If you want to be (*arguably*) safer when using the Clang compiler, use `__typeof__()`. This way you won't be affected if the C Language Dialect being used for compilation changes or if someone decides to turn off the allowance of **'typeof'**.

Comment: What about __typeof?

Answer (score 6):

Hope this will be helpfull:

> -ansi and the various -std options disable certain keywords. This causes trouble when you want to use GNU C extensions, or a general-purpose header file that should be usable by all programs, including ISO C programs. The keywords asm, typeof and inline are not available in programs compiled with -ansi or -std (although inline can be used in a program compiled with -std=c99 or -std=c11). The ISO C99 keyword restrict is only available when -std=gnu99 (which will eventually be the default) or -std=c99 (or the equivalent -std=iso9899:1999), or an option for a later standard version, is used.
>
> The way to solve these problems is to put ‘__’ at the beginning and end of each problematical keyword. For example, use __asm__ instead of asm, and __inline__ instead of inline.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#c-language-features

Comment: This explains `__typeof__`, but what about `__typeof`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心996ICU六四事件 AFAIK GCC/clang support to wrap non-standard keywords with `__` on both sides, however, it will not enforce the presence of the trailing `__`. So `__typeof` is just a `__typeof__` where the trailing underscores are missing and the compiler doesn't care. Works also with `__asm` and `__inline`.