# iOS Objective-C: weakSelf Syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

Nearly every example of the `weakSelf` pattern I encounter online has the syntax

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

But the compiler complains about this syntax in the latest version of Xcode, requiring:

```
__weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
```

Did the syntax change, or am i missing an import? I tried pulling in `<objc/runtime.h>` but no change.

Stealthy bonus question: Why not just cast it explicitly?

```
__weak MyBoffoClass *weakSelf = self;
```

I found one answer here that said it was better to cast it directly, but no reasoning as to why.

Comment: Reasonable looking answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877415/difference-between-typeof-typeof-and-typeof-objective-c

Comment: Thanks, I searched for typeof but didn't get that result, clearly should have dug deeper, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the help from @danh pointing me at [Difference between typeof, __typeof and __typeof__ (Objective-c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877415/difference-between-typeof-typeof-and-typeof-objective-c), I discovered the issue was in the compiler settings.

Click on the project at the top of the `Project Navigator` window, click on `Build Settings`, and choose to `View All`:
[image: Choosing Settings]

Next scroll down to Apple LLVM *n*.*n* - Language and examine the settings:
[image: Language Settings]

In my case, the language dialect was set to C99, which doesn't support the GNU compiler macros and other extensions to the C language.

Not sure why it's set like this for the project (the project architect doesn't recall why), I just have to allow for the fact in my reading of StackOverflow code snippets. Better than introducing something by changing it because I am a lazy typist.