# __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self OR __weak MyObject *weakSelf = self?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

What is preferable to use here and why?

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

or

```
__weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
```

Obviously, `__weak id weakSelf = self;` would be the least desirable, as we would not get type checking, is that correct?

However, between the first two... which is desirable and why?

Also, any reason to use __typeof instead of typeof, if clang supports using typeof?

Comment: It's not an opinon-based question. These two statements are handled by the compiler in a different way so both usages have their pros and cons.

Comment: @MichałCiuba They have pros and cons but there is no definitive answer. Different people will read pros and cons and choose differently. Therefore it's opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently starting writing it like this:

```
__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
```

Using the `__typeof` version lets you use a code snippet so it's way faster, and will also be consistent throughout your code.

This isn't the common form, as most people put the `__weak` variable qualifier at the beginning, but according to the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html the variable qualifier goes after the type.

Once inside the block, I use:

```
__typeof(weakSelf) __strong strongSelf = weakSelf;
if (!strongSelf) return;
```

to obtain a strong reference again.

Both of those are code snippets so I don't actually do much typing, or have to remember the exact syntax.

Comment: can you elaborate on the code snippet? Are these little macros you can create within the xcode IDE?

Comment: Sure, Xcode has some code snippet support included, but I prefer to use Dash https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash-3-api-docs-snippets/id449589707?mt=12&uo=4&at=11lMGu&pt=17255&ct=SO since I also use it for docs. It lets you set up a keyword that when you type it, it's automatically replaced by the snippet. So I use `weakSelf#` and `strongSelf#` for those two. That's all I ever have to type in and I get all the complicated syntax consistently done for me. I also have snippets for setting up common blocks etc since it's a pain to remember the syntax for those.

Comment: thanks. Also, is there a need to define __strong once in the block. That would be the default correct? Or do you place that there more for symmetry?

Comment: I believe you're correct that you don't need the `__strong` qualifier since it is the default, but I use it to increase the readability. It makes it explicitly clear to anyone else reading the code why we're creating another variable.

Comment: I'm going mad trying to drag one line of code into snippets to create a snippet. Is there a menu option or keyboard shortcut? I literally cannot grab one line of text and drag it over. Tried 50 times.

Comment: I haven't used Xcode's snippets, so no idea how you'd add more. In Dash, it's easy, just hit the + and type in what you want. TextExpander  https://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander is another common tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

The first is more convenient, because the code is the same regardless of class. You can use an Xcode code snippet to insert the `typeof`-using line of code with fewer keystrokes. You also have less work to do if you change the name of your class.

I don't know of any downside to using the `typeof`-version except maybe that it's a little harder to understand.

[If you use `__typeof__` instead of `typeof`, your code will compile regardless of the compiler's dialect setting.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508311/77567)

Answer (score -3):

As you probably know `__typeof__()` "expands" to the concrete type of the argument. If the argument is `self` and the concrete type of `self` is `MyObject` (that is your case), it is simply the same.

So the first form has simply another indirection with the usual advantage and disadvantage of indirections:

- The indirected form is more flexibel, because the indirection follows changes.
- The indirected form is less readable, because the the reader has to understand the indirection in his mind.

Personally I would prefer the second form. But more important: Personally I would prefer to waste my time for more important questions. ;-)

Would you write:

```
__typeof__(self) copy = [self copy];
```

I wouldn't.