# iOS take textview value to alertController.textFields. in alert controller block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

How can I pass the textview value to the alertController textFields block?

I have the textview component call "myTextView"

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView
```

I set the alertcontroller below:

```
myAlertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"pass the value in alertcontroller" preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
myAlertControllerOKAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"sure" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:nil];
[myAlertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.text = [self.myTextView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
}];
[myAlertController addAction: myAlertControllerOKAction];
```

But I set the myTextView.text in the myAlertController block,

```
textField.text = [self.myTextView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

}];
```

It will show

> Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle

How can I get the textview value in the alert controller block for textfield use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use weak `self` in block:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[myAlertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.text = [weakSelf.myTextView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
}];
```

If you use strong `self` in a block, it may cause `self` not be released.

[Always pass weak reference of self into block in ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030873/always-pass-weak-reference-of-self-into-block-in-arc)

Comment: I trace the weakSelf.myTextView.text in the block, it will show nil. did you known why?

Comment: @dickfala Do you initialize `myTextView ` or assign value to it?

Comment: Hi, myTextView is from  IBOutlet  UITextView *myTextView, I had key some words, then click button show the myAlertController, I need pass the myTextView content to the myAlertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler block. But I can't get the value using the __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

Comment: I don't known why I key the some words in the textview, the textview(call myTextView) is IBOutlet in header property.  Then I click a button to show the alert, the alert have textfield, I want to show the myTextView content on the alert textfield. But I don't known why I got the nil in the addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler block about alert controller.

Comment: @dickfala I create a project [Github TestAlertController](https://github.com/tomfriwel/TestAlertController) and it works fine for me. You can download it to see what difference to your.

Comment: thank you very much, I found the problem, the problem is I declare the myAlertController in the viewdidload, and the addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler is in the viewdidload, So I present the alertcontroller , it always get the nil contents. thank you very much, tom.

Answer (score 0):

Create a weak variable of your "self" like this outside the block:

Swift 3:

```
weak var w_self = self
```

Objective-C:

```
__weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
```

Then use this one inside the block instead of the "self".

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a weak reference to self before accessing `myTextView` inside your block:

```
...
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[myAlertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {

    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.text = [weakSelf.myTextView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

}];
...
```

Comment: I try to add the weakSelf, I found I can't got the textview text content in the addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler block. Did you known how to resolve? thanks.

Comment: I trace the weakSelf.myTextView.text in the  addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler block, It will get the nil value.

Comment: I changed "typeof" to "__typeof" it probably fix.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877415/difference-between-typeof-typeof-and-typeof-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have pointed out, in Swift or ObjC you can create a `weak` reference to an object to avoid a strong retain cycle inside the closure.

ObjC:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[myAlertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.text = [weakSelf.myTextView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
}];
```

Swift `weak`:

```
myAlertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: { [weak self] (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
    // Notice the guard to make sure myTextView is unwrapped
    guard let weakTextView = weak.myTextView,
        let weakText = weakTextView.text,
        weakText.characters.count > 0 else {
        return
    }
    textField.keyboardType .default
    textField.text = weakText.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
})
```

Swift `unowned`:

```
myAlertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: { [unowned self] (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
    // Notice the use of unowned, unlike weak, unowned does not have to be unwrapped to avoid nil

    textField.keyboardType .default
    textField.text = unowned.weakTextView.text.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
})
```

In the example with `unowned`, noticed how I do not unwrap my `unowned` reference like I do with the weak one. This is because `unowned` is not an optional and we do not run the risk of running into `nil` when using `unowned`.  I personally like using `unowned` better.