# Implementing min function in C by using typeof compiler extension gives error

Tags: c, gcc, clang, max, min

When i attempted to implement min function in C as C lacks this function the compiler gives an error. I've used type of for implementing it just like this

[MIN and MAX in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c)

[My code](https://gist.github.com/8befd9ba16f374c827a311812815f78a)

For quick reference:

```
>#define min(a,b) \
  ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
  typeof (b) _b = (b); \        //Min defined
  _a < _b ? _a : _b; })
  .
  .
  .
  c= min(c+floor(1.0/f), bi.biWidth) ;
  r= min(r+floor(1.0/f),abs(bi.biHeight)) ;
```

Error generated:

```
 >make resize
 clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall       
 -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow    resize.c  -lcrypt -lcs50      
 -lm  -o resize

resize.c:191:18: error: implicit declaration of function 'typeof' is    
invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          c= min(c+floor(1.0/f), bi.biWidth) ;
             ^
resize.c:11:6: note: expanded from macro 'min'
({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
 ^
 resize.c:191:18: error: expected ';' after expression
 resize.c:11:17: note: expanded from macro 'min'
 ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
            ^

 resize.c:191:18: error: use of undeclared identifier '_a'

 resize.c:11:17: note: expanded from macro 'min'
 ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
            ^

 resize.c:191:18: error: expected ';' after expression

 resize.c:12:18: note: expanded from macro 'min'
  typeof (b) _b = (b); \

                  ^

 resize.c:191:18: error: use of undeclared identifier '_b'

 resize.c:12:18: note: expanded from macro 'min'
  typeof (b) _b = (b); \
             ^

 resize.c:191:18: error: use of undeclared identifier '_a'

 resize.c:13:5: note: expanded from macro 'min'
 _a < _b ? _a : _b; })
 ^

 resize.c:191:18: error: use of undeclared identifier '_b'

 resize.c:13:10: note: expanded from macro 'min'
 _a < _b ? _a : _b; })
     ^

 resize.c:191:18: error: use of undeclared identifier '_b'

 resize.c:13:20: note: expanded from macro 'min'
 _a < _b ? _a : _b; })
               ^

 resize.c:193:13: error: expected ';' after expression
     r= min(r+floor(1.0/f),abs(bi.biHeight)) ;
        ^

 resize.c:11:17: note: expanded from macro 'min'
  ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
            ^

 resize.c:193:13: error: use of undeclared identifier '_a'

 resize.c:11:17: note: expanded from macro 'min'
 ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
            ^

 resize.c:193:13: error: expected ';' after expression

 resize.c:12:18: note: expanded from macro 'min'
  typeof (b) _b = (b); \
             ^

 resize.c:193:13: error: use of undeclared identifier '_b'

 resize.c:12:18: note: expanded from macro 'min'
  typeof (b) _b = (b); \
             ^

 resize.c:193:13: error: use of undeclared identifier '_a'

 resize.c:13:5: note: expanded from macro 'min'
 _a < _b ? _a : _b; })
 ^

 resize.c:193:13: error: use of undeclared identifier '_b'

 resize.c:13:10: note: expanded from macro 'min'
 _a < _b ? _a : _b; })
     ^

 resize.c:193:13: error: use of undeclared identifier '_b'

 resize.c:13:20: note: expanded from macro 'min'
 _a < _b ? _a : _b; })
               ^

 15 errors generated.
```

Comment: How do you expect us to say what's wrong with your code if you don't show us your code?  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh I'm extremely Sorry. I'll add a code snippet!

Comment: @PrabhatSharma add the code snippet *verbatim in the question* please, thanks!

Comment: I've added the link and marked the use of min through comments!

Comment: @PrabhatSharma voting to close here: code must be included in the question, not in an external link.

Comment: Sorry, but I've done both. Since the actual code was quite long I didn't include the whole!

Comment: `typeof (b) _b = (b); \        //Min defined` --> typeof (b) _b = (b);         //Min defined\

Comment: @bluepixy: You're right. I don't saw that first!

Comment: Nopes @BLUEPIXY that doesn't make any difference!

Comment: You should check if your compiler supports typeof. If not you have to think about an alternative.

Comment: Clang doesn't support typeof :(

Comment: Note: `typeof` is a [compiler extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12081502/2410359) not in C11, C99,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
#define min(a,b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
      __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); // Min defined \
      _a < _b ? _a : _b; })
```

Your comment should **not** be after the `\` but before it.
Also you write typeof without the underscores. It is recommended to use them, the explanation is given [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877415/difference-between-typeof-typeof-and-typeof-objective-c).

> `typeof()`, `__typeof__()` and `__typeof()` are compiler-specific extensions to the C language, because standard C does not include such an operator.

---

**Macro without typeof:**

If your compiler does **not** support the `typeof` "operator", you could define the min macro without typeof:

```
#define min(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

But with that you will have side effects when using postfix or prefix in/decrement operators on variables, because a double evaluation will occur.

---

**Inline function:**

The other possibility to make it safe is an inline function. It will be typesafe and no double evaluation will happen:

```
inline int min(int a, int b)
{
   if (a < b)
   {
      return a;
   }
   return b;
}
```

You loose type genericity, but there is no other way. You could also think of using double since integers will be implicitly casted. But remember the loose of precision.

Comment: What's the difference between both? I've used this documentation code of typeof  [gcc doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)

Comment: Moreover it didn't solved the problem! The errors are almost same except instead of typeof there is _typeof_

Comment: Means it's all compiler specific and we should not use it. Right? But how then we define min or max function in C?

Comment: You could  implement it without of the use of **typeof**: `#define min(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))`.

Comment: But this will cause problem in some cases like if we write (++a, ++b) etc.   See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c      But I admit this will not cause any problem in my case!

Comment: You could use an inline function as I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks! @Andre Kampling