# unknown type name 'off64_t'

Tags: python, mingw

I am trying to install pysnmp on a Windows 32-bit machine using easy_install with Mingw as my compiler.  However, (after fixing numerous other issues) I get the error "unknown type name 'off64_t'"

This comes from "c:\mingw\include\io.h:301:1" as the first reported line, with 301:36,302:1,and 302:39 as the other three instances.

I have already read this thread [Unknown type name ‘off64_t’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663897/unknown-type-name-off64-t)
But as I am not on a Linux system nor do I have access to the source code of the easy_install package, I do not believe this helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been solved.  Apparently in MinGW, some types are not properly updated when a certain variable is set.

To fix the issue, I manually edited the 4 instances of 'off64_t' in mingw\include\io.h to be '_off64_t'  I then had to update mingw\include\unistd and change 'off_t' to '_off_t'.

Refer to http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2024/ for more information, there are other similar reports which address this issue.

Also, I'm a dumb person and line numbers are of course different for every system.