# Default nginx client_max_body_size

Tags: nginx

I have been getting the nginx error:

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
```

I have been able to update my `client_max_body_size` in the server section of my nginx.conf file to 20M and this has fixed the issue. However, what is the default nginx `client_max_body_size`?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

The default value for `client_max_body_size` directive is **1 MiB**.

It can be set in `http`, `server` and `location` context — as in the [most cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104731/directive-inheritance-in-nested-location-blocks#answer-32126596), 
this **directive in a nested block takes precedence over the same directive in the ancestors blocks**.

Excerpt from the [ngx_http_core_module documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size):

> ```
> Syntax:   client_max_body_size size;
> Default:  client_max_body_size 1m;
> Context:  http, server, location
> ```
>
> Sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body, specified in
>   the “Content-Length” request header field. If the size in a request
>   exceeds the configured value, the 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error
>   is returned to the client. Please be aware that browsers cannot
>   correctly display this error. Setting size to 0 disables checking of
>   client request body size.

Don't forget to [reload configuration](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html)
by `nginx -s reload` or `service nginx reload` commands prepending with `sudo` (if any).

Comment: Coming in late to note that you should use `nginx -t` to test your configuration before running `nginx -s reload` to apply the configuration changes. It can't guarantee your configuration is correct, but it will catch syntax errors or invalid values.

Comment: Yes, but in any case, `nginx -s reload` will not apply a syntactically incorrect configuration but will report error.

Comment: What is the *maximum* value that Nginx supports for this directive? There's nothing in the docs. [Apache supports 2GB max](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody).

Comment: @DanDascalescu, the maximum value depends on `off_t` type size (see [`ngx_http_core_module.h`](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.h)). In the case of 64-bit executable [`off_t` size is 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073667/where-to-find-the-complete-definition-of-off-t-type#answer-14351239), and the max value should be 2^63 bytes.

Comment: @ruvim according to my testing, it should really be `MiB` (not MB), but do you have a documentation reference for that please ? :-) thank you **others PHP:** note that it has to  be a slightly bigger than PHP `post_max_size` & `upload_max_filesize` since body size is not just the file but other body text parts too.

Comment: @jave.web, if you mean 1024 vs 1000 multiplier, then in the context of RAM the term "megabyte" is often incorrectly used instead of the term "mebibyte". And the nginx documentation is not an exclusion, — see [measurement units](https://nginx.org/en/docs/syntax.html) and the corresponding [source code](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/release-1.23.1/src/core/ngx_parse.c#L13).

Answer (score 44):

**Nginx** default value for `client_max_body_size` is `1MB`

You can update this value by three different way

#### 1. Set in `http` block which affects all server blocks (virtual hosts).

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

#### 2. Set in `server` block, which affects a particular site/app.

```
server {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

#### 3. Set in `location` block, which affects a particular directory (uploads) under a site/app.

```
location /uploads {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

For more info [click here](https://www.tecmint.com/limit-file-upload-size-in-nginx/)

Comment: Does it matter if its capital or lower case M?  Ie 100m vs 100M

Comment: @AdamHughes, I think it is case insensitive.

Answer (score 31):

Pooja Mane's answer worked for me, but I had to put the *client_max_body_size* variable inside of *http* section.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

You can increase body size in nginx configuration file as

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
>
> client_max_body_size 100M;

Restart nginx to apply the changes.

> sudo service nginx restart

Comment: set it 0 for unlimit

Comment: Can you also run  `nginx -s reload`  for the new configuration to take effect?

Comment: No, don't set it to unlimited unless you are setting up a honeypot to invite Slow-HTTP DoS attacks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to increase client_max_body_size in `nginx.conf` file. This is the basic step. But if your backend `laravel` then you have to do some changes in the `php.ini` file as well. It depends on your backend. Below I mentioned file location and condition name.

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.
```

After open the file adds this into HTTP section.

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend increase the client_max_body_size on the http or server block, you must to increase it from http -> server -> location (the target). Example:

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size: 1m;
    ...
    server {
        ...
        client_max_body_size: 2m;
        ...
        location ~* ^/upload/(.*)$ { # the target
            ...
            client_max_body_size: 100m;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the setting for this field doesn't work this way. In our settings, if we set like this, the upload endpoint will end up reject file size over 1m.

Comment: I have been experiencing the same thing. It seems it is evaluating the http block or server block's client_max_body_size before and never considering the client_max_body_size from the location block. I've been trying to do the same thing as above and I keep getting 413

Answer (score -2):

This works for the new AWS Linux 2 environment. To fix this - you need to wrap your configuration file. You should have, if you're using Docker, a zip file (mine is called `deploy.zip`) that contains your `Dockerrun.aws.json`. If you don't - it's rather easy to modify, just zip your deploy via
`zip -r deploy.zip Dockerrun.aws.json`

With that - you now need to add a `.platform` folder as follows:

```
APP ROOT
├── Dockerfile
├── Dockerrun.aws.json
├── .platform
│   └── nginx
│       └── conf.d
│           └── custom.conf
```

You can name your `custom.conf` whatever you want, and can have as many files as you want. Inside `custom.conf`, you simply need to place the following inside

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Or whatever you want for your config. With that - modify your zip to now be

`zip -r deploy.zip Dockerrun.aws.json .platform`

And deploy. Your Nginx server will now respect the new command

More details here: https://blog.benthem.io/2022/04/05/modifying-nginx-settings-on-elasticbeanstalk-with-docker.html

Comment: IMO your answer is too specific in ways not required by the original question.