# How to increase body size in requests Svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am making some request that exceeds the limit of svelte of 512kb, I have checked this page on svelte docs
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables-body-size-limit, it says that i have to set something to 0 and implement a custom check, and i am using adapter-vercel(because i have tried that env method didn't worked), idk how to do it, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

#### Change body size limit

To remove the limit, locally, add this to a `.env` file at the root of your project:

```bash
BODY_SIZE_LIMIT=0
```

And in Vercel, add an [environment variable](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables) with the same name and value.

Note that you can also set it to a custom value in kiliobytes:

```bash
BODY_SIZE_LIMIT=1024 # 1mb
```

#### Custom check

Then you'd need to create a `src/hooks.server.js` file with a [`handle`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handle) method that looks at the request body and rejects it if too large. Here is [an example from Rich Harris](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/6542#issuecomment-1236108566):

```js
export function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  const length = +(event.request.headers.get('content-length') ?? '0');
  if (length > MAX_SIZE) {
    throw error(413);
  }

  return resolve(event);
}
```

Where `MAX_SIZE` matches an environment variable you set.

Related post: [How to increase request size made to api/+server.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75330213/how-to-increase-request-size-made-to-api-server-js)