# I want to use ftruncate to create a file with fixed size, but how can I deal with off_t type?

Tags: c, linux

SYNOPSIS

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    int ftruncate(int fd, off_t length);
```

Someone says that offset types are usually long integers.
So I use %ld to scanf it as follows:

```
    off_t size;
    scanf("%ld",&size);
    ftruncate(fout,size);
```

But the compiler warn :expected "int" but argumant is of type "struct FILE *"
What can I deal with it?

Comment: The error isn't about off_t at all, it's about your _first_ parameter to ftruncate.

Comment: The first parameter needs to be a char* not a FILE*.

Comment: Not a `char*` either, but a filedescriptor, which is an `int`. In summary, you just fail to call `ftruncate()` correctly.

Comment: For your reference, the official Linux man-page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html

Answer (score 2):

The `ftruncate` function expects its first argument to be a file descriptor, while you pass `struct FILE*` instead, apparently. The correct way is:

```
ftruncate(fileno(fout),size);
```

Comment: I was about to write this - but here is the link to the relevant manual page http://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno

Answer (score 2):

OP has 2 issues.  The first, wrong use of `ftruncate()` is well answered by [@Oleg Andriyanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691481/2410359)

The 2nd issue if how to use `scanf()` with `off_t`.  `off_t` is a signed type: [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9073762/2410359).

If `off_t` was always `long`, then there would be no reason to define a new type.  So assuming `off_t` is `long` is a not portable.

To read an integer that is signed with unknown width, suggest reading it using the maximum width.

```
intmax_t wide_int;
scanf("%jd", &wide_int);
off_t size = (off_t) wide_int;
```

The above omits error checking. Robust error checking code would use `fgets()`, `strtoimax()`,  etc.