# how to find off_t size correctly

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have below piece of code in my module and im compiling it with ICC compiler.

```
/**
 * Static (compile-time) assertion.
 * Basically, use COND to dimension an array.  If COND is false/zero the
 * array size will be -1 and we'll get a compilation error.
 */

    #define STATIC_ASSERT(COND) \
       do { \
          (void) sizeof(char [1 - 2*!(COND)]); \
       } while (0)
     #define LARGE_OFF_T ((((off_t) 1 << 31) << 31) - 1 + \
                         (((off_t) 1 << 31) << 31)) 
       STATIC_ASSERT(LARGE_OFF_T % 2147483629 == 721 &&
                     LARGE_OFF_T % 2147483647 == 1);
```

the above assertion fails with array size must be grater than 0.

Can anyone help me understand when does this assertion fail and how to fix it ? 
I have tried compiling with _DFILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 but in vain.

Comment: To find the _size_ of `off_t`, `sizeof(off_t) * CHAR_BIT` is sufficient for C code - but not for pre-processor math,

Comment: If the text of your question is correct, you're incorrectly writing `_DFILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` where you mean `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`.

Comment: Thanks I missed it. That solved the issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code attempts to determine whether `off_t` is at least 64 bits wide, including a sign bit.

In `STATIC_ASSERT`, if `COND` is true, `1 - 2*!(COND)` evaluates as `1-2*!1` = `1-2*0` = `1`, and the array size is 1, which is fine. If `COND` is false, it evaluates as `1-2*!0` = `1-2*1` = `-1`, which causes the compiler to issue a diagnostic. So `STATIC_ASSERT` acts to generate a compiler message if `COND` is false.

`LARGE_OFF_T` attempts to perform some arithmetic in the `off_t` type. If `off_t` is at least 64 bits wide, `(off_t) 1 << 31) << 31` evaluates to 2<sup>62</sup>. Then the whole expression evaluates to 2<sup>62</sup> − 1 + 2<sup>62</sup> = 2<sup>63</sup>−1. This number has a remainder of 721 modulo 2147483629 and 1 modulo 2147483647, so it passes the test and does not cause the compiler to issue a diagnostic.

If `off_t` is, say, 32 bits wide and unsigned, `(off_t) 1 << 31) << 31` evaluates to 0, and the whole expression evaluates to 0 − 1 + 0 = 2<sup>32</sup>−1 (since unsigned arithmetic wraps), which has a remainder modulo 2147483629 of 37, so it fails the test, and the compiler generates a diagnostic.

The test is not reliable if `off_t` is signed. If `off_t` is signed and 32 bits wide, the behavior of `(off_t) 1 << 31` is not defined by the C standard. If it is signed and less than 63 bits wide, the behavior of `((off_t) 1 << 31) << 31` is undefined, and, if it is signed and less than 64 bits wide, the final addition is undefined.

If the test is failing for you, you need to correct it by adjusting the build conditions so that `off_t` is an integer type that is at least 64 bits wide. There is insufficient information in the question to say how to do this.

There are indications in the code that it expects `off_t` to be a signed type. If it were known to be unsigned, then one could ensure it were at least 64 bits simply by testing `18446744073709551615u <= (off_t) -1`. And value that the code attempts to construct, 2<sup>63</sup>−1, is the maximum value of a 64-bit signed integer, rather than an unsigned integer. This is unfortunate because, as indicated above, if `off_t` is signed and less than 64 bits wide, the operations have undefined behavior. A better approach might be to test `9223372036854775807 == (off_t) 9223372036854775807`, because overflow during conversion to a signed integer type is at least implementation-defined, rather than not defined by the C standard. One might also settle for `64 <= sizeof(off_t) * CHAR_BIT`. (`CHAR_BIT` is defined in `<limits.h>`.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: explanation of the mechanism is nice but I think OP's real problem (an XY Problem) is that they're incorrectly attempting to override glibc's 32-bit `off_t` default and failing to do so because of wrong macro name.

Comment: @R..: Out of my knowledge, and, as the penultimate paragraph says, “There is insufficient information in the question to say how to do this.” There is some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073667/where-to-find-the-complete-definition-of-off-t-type), but somebody should enter an answer about getting the desired `off_t`; I do not think I am going to investigate it, at least not today.

Comment: @chux: I thought I edited the `u` in previously, but it seems the edit got lost somehow.