# Why does fseek have "long int offset" instead of "long long int offset"?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, long-integer, fseek, c-standard-library

C2x, 7.21.9.2 The fseek function:

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence);
> ```

Why does `fseek` have `long int offset` instead of `long long int offset`?

It seems that on operating systems with data model [LLP64 or ILP32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) (e.g. Microsoft Windows) the `2147483647` (2 GB) may be insufficient.

Note: POSIX's [lseek](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) has `off_t offset`, where `off_t` "[isn't very rigorously defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9073762/1778275)".

Comment: That's why every C library usually have 64-bit extensions, to handle 64-bit offsets. MSVC, for example, have [`_fseeki64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=msvc-170). Regarding `lseek`, Linux have [`lseek64`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lseek64.3.html) which uses the guaranteed 64-bit type `off64_t`.

Comment: It's an unfortunate historical precedent.  Clearly (at least, with 20/20 hindsight) it would have been better to have defined `fseek` and `ftell` in terms of `off_t`, or something.

Comment: We're stuck with these kludges and compromises, seemingly forever.  Back in the early seventies, the original `seek` call gave way to `lseek`, as Unix learned how to deal with 32-bit (!) file sizes.  Fast forward to today, and we've got this litany of `stat64` and `_fseeki64` and `lseek64` calls.  ("`lseek64`" is a particularly ghastly misnomer; it should clearly be "`seek64`" or "`llseek`".)

Comment: I can see, some 10 years from now, people asking, *"Why is it `long long int` (64-bit) and not `long long long int` (128-bit)?"*

Comment: @AdrianMole Hopefully will switch to qubits before it happens.

Comment: @SteveSummit `llseek` might be confusing as linux already has `_llseek` which splits a 64 bit offset into two 32 bit args. It might be ghastly but given that we already have `lseek` we probably want to keep `lseek` as _part_ of the replacement name(s). When I'm looking at a code base and asking the question: _Where are all the places seeking is done?_ I'd like to be able to do a `grep` on `lseek` and get a match on either `lseek` or `lseek64` On 64 bit systems `lseek` works by default. For 32 bit, we can do: `#define _LARGEFILE*_SOURCE` and `lseek` works

Comment: @SteveSummit Hence the existence of `fseeko` and `ftello` in POSIX-1.2001.

Comment: `long long int` was added in C99, but `fseek` was already defined to use `long int` offsets before C99.

Comment: @AdrianMole `long long int` supports 9.22 EB (exabytes). Should be enough for the next 50 years I guess. Example: 1 hour of 512K (sic!) video takes ~400 TB. Not sure though about the 512K video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C Standard was formalized in 1990 when most hard drives were smaller than 2 GB.  The prototype for `fseek()` was already in broad use with a `long` type offset and 32 bits seemed large enough for all purposes, especially since the corresponding system call used the same API already. They did add `fgetpos()` and `fsetpos()` for exotic file systems where a simple long offset did not carry all the necessary information for seeking, but kept the `fpos_t` type opaque.

After a few years, when 64-bit offsets became necessary, many operating systems added 64-bit versions of the system calls and POSIX introduced `fseeko()` and `ftello()` to provide a high level interface for larger offsets. These extensions are not necessary anymore for 64-bit versions of common operating systems (linux, OS/X) but Microsoft decided to keep it's `long`, or more precisely `LONG`, type at 32-bits, solidifying this issue and other ones too such as `size_t` being larger than `unsigned long`.  This very unfortunate decision plagues C developers on Win64 platforms ever since and forces them to use non portable APIs for large files.

Changing `fseek` and `ftell` prototypes would create more problems with existing software as it would break compatibility, so it will not happen.

Some other historical shortcomings are even more surprising, such as the prototype for `fgets`:

```
char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
```

Why did they use `int` instead of `size_t` is a mystery: back in 1990, `int` and `size_t` had the same size on most platforms and it did not make sense to pass a negative value anyway.  Again, this inconsistent API is here to stay.

Comment: Nice point about `fgets`, although, anybody trying to read a line longer than 32767 characters (or, these days, 2147483647 characters!) probably has other problems, anyway. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit: text files with lines longer than 32K are common place: minified JS files for example. System generated XML files can easily break the 2GB barrier, a challenge for `getline()` users :)

Comment: "plagues C developers on Win64 platforms ever since and forces them to use non portable APIs for large files." --> I suspect this is a deliberate [choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: we are on the same page :)

Comment: @chqrlie Files with "lines" longer than 32K are not, IMHO, text files, and no sane person (again, IMHO) reads or processes them a line at a time.

Comment: @SteveSummit Agree about sane people, yet automated systems can and do create exceptionally long strings and it is those that stress code.  Still I generally agree that any input  larger than some N is more likely nefarious than good and deserves error handling rather than allow outside forces to compel code to handle huge strings.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Re: "a deliberate choice": thanks for the link, interesting!

Comment: `This very unfortunate decision plagues C developers on Win64 platforms ever since and forces them to use non portable APIs for large files.` same to programmers on 32-bit \*nix. They all have to use other solutions

Comment: @phuclv: except programmers that must deal with huge files on 32-bit unix know they are in a legacy world and can use standard POSIX functions. Modern unix systems do not have this issue.

Comment: no that's not a legacy world, there are still plenty 32-bit MCUs running Linux and they'll never disappear

Comment: @phuclv: I agree, it is an embedded world where files rarely exceed 2GB, but it is a POSIX world with a standard solution.