# C Library Double Underscore Confusion

Tags: c, namespaces, header-files, conventions

I have read all the questions I can find about this, but nobody has yet addressed my confusion.

If I understand correctly, the use of a double underscore at the beginning of a method or variable name in library code is simply a namespace convention. It allows the operating system code to avoid clashing with any application code.

Why, then, does my `/usr/include/string.h` contain, for example, the following function declaration;

```
extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, __const char *__restrict __src)
    __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
```

Ignoring the `__THROW` and `__nonnull ((1, 2));` parts, I have the following questions;

- Why do they use double-underscore for the *local* variable names `__dest` and `__src`, when surely these are only ever reachable by the implementation (presumably in `string.c` or similar), and can never clash with my code. (as an aside, I never really understood why forward declarations *needed* parameter names, shouldn't the types alone be enough?)
- Why is the function name not `__strcpy`? Does `string.h` not count as part of the operating system?
- Why are the words `const` and `restrict` altered to use double-underscore? Aren't they already reserved words in the C99 (or earlier?) standard?

Clearly I've got my wires crossed somewhere along the line, if someone could clear this up for me that would be great.

Comment: The accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449181/what-does-double-underscore-const-mean-in-c covers at least parts of your question.

Comment: @Michael thanks, this was one of the ones I was piecing information together from, but I will re-read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The parameter names are with `__` such that they don't clash with
  macros that a program might have defined. Another option would have been to omit the parameter names completely from the declaration.
- It is `strcpy` because that is the symbol (of the C library) that is
  declared here
- The `const` and `restrict` keywords are protected in case somebody
  uses a compiler that doesn't implement them, yet.

Comment: Ahh so parameter names can be omissed from a forward declaration? And When would I see a function with a name such as `__myfunction`?

Comment: @lynks, yes the parameters names can be omitted. Functions as `__myfunction` would be "private" functions of the C library implementation that you are not supposed to use directly but that for one reason or another must be visible as external functions.

Comment: Thanks, I shall continue to use these things until they click.