# using the typedef keyword with a struct

Tags: c, struct

What exactly is the purpose of using a typedef together with a struct and giving it two names, often one in capital letters?

Today I was looking at a winsock tutorial and came across the struct definition below.

```
// IPv4 AF_INET sockets:
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};

typedef struct in_addr {
  union {
    struct {
      u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4;
    } S_un_b;
    struct {
      u_short s_w1,s_w2;
    } S_un_w;
    u_long S_addr;
  } S_un;
} IN_ADDR, *PIN_ADDR, FAR *LPIN_ADDR;


struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
    char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
};
```

What exactly does this line do?

> IN_ADDR, *PIN_ADDR, FAR *LPIN_ADDR;

Comment: It is creating one type synonymous to `struct in_addr` and two pointer types to this type.

Comment: Please do not `typedef` pointers, such as `*PIN_ADDR, FAR *LPIN_ADDR`.

Comment: It seems strange to `typedef` a `struct` whose only member is a `union`. Why not just `typedef `the `union`?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c

Comment: hiding pointer in `typedef` is a very bad practice for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly is the purpose of using a typedef together with a struct and giving it two names, often one in capital letters?

There are three primary components to

> ```
> typedef struct in_addr {
>     // members ... 
> } IN_ADDR, *PIN_ADDR, FAR *LPIN_ADDR;
> ```

- several identifiers that are being declared: `IN_ADDR`, `PIN_ADDR`, and `LPIN_ADDR`.  As far as C is concerned, there is no significance to the fact that these are capitalized; presumably that is an aspect of the chosen coding style.
- the types being declared for those identifiers, respectively `struct in_addr`, `struct in_addr *` and `struct in_addr FAR *`.  The type declaration additionally incorporates a definition of type `struct in_addr`, which is optional because a struct tag (`in_addr`) is given.  The definition could have instead been given separately or not at all:

  ```
  typedef struct in_addr IN_ADDR, *PIN_ADDR, FAR *LPIN_ADDR;

  struct in_addr {
      // members ...
  };
  ```
- the storage class of the declarations, `typedef`, which indicates that instead of those identifiers referring to objects with associated storage, they serve as aliases for their declared types.

Overall, then, the statement declares `IN_ADDR`, `PIN_ADDR`, and `LPIN_ADDR` as aliases for three different, but related, types.

Answer (score 1):

This creates the types `IN_ADDR, *PIN_ADDR, FAR *LPIN_ADDR`, which are synonymous with `struct in_addr` which in turn refers to the structure definintion given.  This practice is is useful when you want to typedef a structure with a self reference, but don't want to add the `struct` keyword before each declaration::

```
typedef struct _SomeStruct_t{
    int                    someVal;
    struct _SomeStruct_t  *pNext;
} SomeStruct_t;

SomeStruct_t  gSomeStruct;
```

You can't set `pNext` to be a pointer to `SomeStruct_t` because it hasn't been defined at that point, so you use `struct _SomeStruct_t` instead.

Comment: And note that this answer shows that tag `_SomeStruct_t` can be used for the self-referencing member `*pnext`. However, you should avoid the use of [leading `_underscore` naming style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39625502/4142924).

Answer (score 0):

You use typedef to create an alias for the struct type, so that you don't have to type it out fully the next time you want to use it. If you didn't have the typedef, any time you want to use `in_addr` you would have to declare it as `struct in_addr`. The typedef allows you to declare it as `IN_ADDR`. When the typedefed name does not have an asterisk, it creates an alias for the type, and a name preceded by an asterisk, as in `*IN_ADDR` creates an alias for a pointer to the type, so you can write `PIN_ADDR` instead of `struct in_addr*`.