# Pointer to array stored in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I've got a struct x:

```
struct x {
    __s32 array[10];
};
```

How can I create a pointer to array `x->array`, if I've got only pointer to stucture?

Comment: To *which* array?

Comment: `&(x->array)` perhaps?

Comment: @HermannDöppes maybe it's the array member variable?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I believe Hermann's point is that a field declared in a structure, that has an array type, is not an array. A field in *a particular instance* of the structure is an array.

Comment: @immibis Quite right, agree.

Comment: Note that identifiers that begin with a double underscore are "always reserved for any use".  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449181/what-does-double-underscore-const-mean-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way is

```
__s32 *pointer = x->array
```

It is equal to

```
__s32 *pointer = &(x->array[0])
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh I suspect OP meant "pointer to first element of array"

Answer (score 2):

The straightaway method is the commonly used way, as

```
 struct x * ptr = NULL;
 //allocation
 __s32 * otherPtr = ptr->array;  //array name decays to pointer to first member
 __s32 (*p) [10] = &(ptr->array); // pointer to whole array.
```

Otherwise, there's another way, but for specialized cases, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.2.1, *Structure and union specifiers*

> [...] A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

So, in case, the array variable is the first member (or only member, as seen in above example) of the structure, the pointer to the structure variable, suitably converted to proper type, will also point to the beginning of the array member variable.

In this case, you can use a cast of `(__s32 (*)[10])`.

Comment: And that is better than &someInstanceOfX->array how?

Comment: @immibis emmm..OK, I did not realize that this was supposed to be a better way, I just thought of an _alternate_ way.