# Segmentation fault in C in K&R fopen and fillbuf

Tags: c, fopen

I'm quite new to C. I faced a problem while studying the last chapter of K&R.

I'm trying to implement `fopen()` and `fillbuf()` function by using system calls, `open` and `read`.

I exactly copied the source code from the book but repeatedly get segmentation error after I compile.

```
    fp->fd = fd;
    fp->cnt = 0;
    fp->base = NULL;
    fp->flag = (*mode=='r')? _READ : _WRITE;
```

Why does error occur? Here is my complete code.

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define PERM 0644
#define EOF (-1)
#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define OPEN_MAX 20

typedef struct _iobuf{
    int cnt;
    char *ptr;
    char *base;
    int flag;
    int fd;
} myFILE;

enum _flags {
    _READ   = 01,
    _WRITE  = 02,
    _UNBUF  = 04,
    _EOF    = 010,
    _ERR    = 020
};

myFILE _iob[OPEN_MAX]={
    {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _READ, 0 },
    {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _WRITE, 1 },
    {0, (char *) 0, (char *) 0, _WRITE | _UNBUF, 2 }
};

#define stdin (&_iob[0])
#define stdout (&_iob[1])
#define stderr (&_iob[2])

#define getc(p)     ( --(p)->cnt>=0 ? (unsigned char) *(p)->ptr++ : _fillbuf(p) )

int _fillbuf(myFILE *fp)
{
    int bufsize;

    if((fp->flag & (_READ|_EOF|_ERR))!=_READ)
        return EOF;

    bufsize=(fp->flag & _UNBUF)? 1 : BUFSIZE;

    if(fp->base==NULL)
        if((fp->base=(char *)malloc(bufsize))==NULL)
            return EOF;

    fp->ptr=fp->base; 
    fp->cnt=read(fp->fd, fp->ptr, bufsize);

    if(--fp->cnt<0){
        if(fp->cnt == -1)
            fp->flag |= _EOF;
        else
            fp->flag |= _ERR;
        return EOF;
    }
    return (unsigned char) *fp->ptr++;  
}

myFILE *myfopen(char *name, char *mode)
{
    int fd;
    myFILE *fp;

    if(*mode!='r' && *mode!='w' && *mode!='a')
          return NULL;
    for(fp=_iob; fp<_iob+OPEN_MAX; fp++)
        if((fp->flag & (_READ | _WRITE))==0)
            break;

    if(fp>=_iob+OPEN_MAX)
        return NULL;

    if(*mode=='w')
         fd=creat(name, PERM);
    else if(*mode=='a'){
        if((fd=open(name, O_WRONLY, 0))==-1)
            fd=creat(name, PERM);   
        lseek(fd, 0L, 2);
    } else
        fd=open(name, O_RDONLY, 0);

    if(fd==-1)
        return NULL;

    fp->fd = fd;
    fp->cnt = 0;
    fp->base = NULL;
    fp->flag = (*mode=='r')? _READ : _WRITE;

        return fp;    
    } 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
myFILE *fp;
int c;

if((fp=myfopen(argv[1], "r"))!=NULL)
    write(1, "opened\n", sizeof("opened\n"));

    while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
        write(1, &c, sizeof(c));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Names starting with `_` at file-level are reserved for the implementation. You are not allowed to use them in user-code. Similar for the standard funcions like `getc`, etc. Your code invokes undefined behaviour. Sidenote: The K&R book is outdated since 18 years and does not teach modern and standard C. Get a book about the current standard C11 or at least C99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Please see [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50654735/6754053). It is more accurate and provides a better diagnosis. My answer works, but there is a better way to do things.**

I see the problem.

```
myFILE *fp;

if(*mode!='r' && *mode!='w' && *mode!='a')
      return NULL;
for(fp=_iob; fp<_iob+OPEN_MAX; fp++)
    if((fp->flag & (_READ | _WRITE))==0) // marked line
        break;
```

When you reach the `marked line`, you try to dereference the `fp` pointer. Since it is (likely, but not certainly) initialized to zero (but I should say `NULL`), you are dereferencing a null pointer. Boom. Segfault.

Here's what you need to change.

```
myFILE *fp = (myFILE *)malloc(sizeof(myFILE));
```

Be sure to `#include <malloc.h>` to use malloc.

Also your `close` function should later `free()` your `myFILE` to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: What malloc.h and not  stdlib.h?

Comment: Why cast result of `malloc`?

Comment: @RoadRunner the C standard specifies that it's a good idea to do this, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @Michi on my system, it's `malloc.h` but `stdlib.h` works also.

Comment: @MarkYisri `the C standard specifies that...` Can you please show me some reference about that?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/ shows a cast to `char *`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc
Do not cast the return of malloc, It can hide errors and doesn't add anything to the code. @MarkYisri You do need to cast in C++ though. But in C you shouldn't

Comment: This diagnosis is wrong. The array `_iob` is an array of structures, not structure pointers. The loop `for (fp =_iob; fp <_iob + OPEN_MAX; fp++)` steps over each element of the array in turn.  It does not encounter any null pointers. The allocation of a `FILE` structure 'works', but isn't necessary. The code shown in the question works correctly as long as you provide a file name and the file is opened successfully.  The code in `main()` crashes if the file cannot be opened, or if no file name is provided on the command line. The spacing in the question's code is inconsistent with that of K&R.

Answer (score 2):

#### A different analysis of the code in the question

The code shown in the question consists of parts, but not all, of the code from K&R "The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition" (1988; my copy is marked 'Based on Draft Proposed ANSI C'), pages 176-178, plus a sample `main` program that is not from the book at all.  The name of the type was changed from `FILE` to `myFILE` too, and `fopen()` was renamed to `myfopen()`.  I note that the expressions in the code in the question have many fewer spaces than the original code in K&R.  The compiler doesn't mind; human readers generally prefer spaces around operators.

As stated in another (later) [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50648250/15168), the diagnosis given by [Mark Yisri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6754053/mark-yisri) in the currently [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41792815/15168) is incorrect — the problem is not a null pointer in the `for` loop.  The prescribed remedy works (as long as the program is invoked correctly), but the memory allocation is not necessary.  Fortunately for all concerned, the `fclose()` function was not included in the implementations, so it wasn't possible to close a file once it was opened.

In particular, the loop:

```
for (fp = _iob; fp < _iob + OPEN_MAX; fp++)
    if ((fp->flag & (_READ | _WRITE)) == 0)
        break;
```

is perfectly OK because the array `_iob` is defined as:

```
FILE _iob[OPEN_MAX] = {
   …initializers for stdin, stdout, stderr…
};
```

This is an array of structures, not structure pointers.  The first three elements are initialized explicitly; the remaining elements are implicitly initialized to all zeros.  Consequently, there is no chance of there being a null pointer in `fp` as it steps through the array.  The loop might also be written as:

```
for (fp = &_iob[0]; fp < &_iob[OPEN_MAX]; fp++)
    if ((fp->flag & (_READ | _WRITE)) == 0)
        break;
```

Empirically, if the code shown in the question (including the `main()`, which was *not* — repeat **not** — written by K&R) is invoked correctly, it works without crashing.  However, the code in the `main()` program does not protect itself from:

- Being invoked without a non-null `argv[1]`.
- Being invoked with a non-existent or non-readable file name in `argv[1]`.

These are very common problems, and with the main program as written, either could cause the program to crash.

Although it is hard to be sure 16 months later, it seems likely to me that the problem was in the way that the program was invoked rather than anything else.  If the main program is written more-or-less appropriately, you end up with code similar to this (you also need to add `#include <string.h>` to the list of included headers):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myFILE *fp;
    int c;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        static const char usage[] = "Usage: mystdio filename\n";
        write(2, usage, sizeof(usage) - 1);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((fp = myfopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        static const char filenotopened[] = "mystdio: failed to open file ";
        write(2, filenotopened, sizeof(filenotopened) - 1);
        write(2, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        write(2, "\n", 1);
        return 1;
    }

    write(1, "opened\n", sizeof("opened\n"));

    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
        write(1, &c, sizeof(c));

    return 0;
}
```

This can't use `fprintf()` etc because the surrogate implementation of the standard I/O library is not complete.  Writing the errors direct to file descriptor 2 (standard error) with `write()` is fiddly, if not painful. It also means that I've taken shortcuts like assuming that the program is called `mystdio` rather than actually using `argv[0]` in the error messages.  However, if it is invoked without any file name (or if more than one file name is given), or if the named file cannot be opened for reading, then it produces a more or less appropriate error message — and does not crash.

#### Leading underscores

Note that the C standard reserves identifiers starting with underscores.
You should not create function, variable or macro names that start with an underscore, in general. [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says (in part):

- *All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.*
- *All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.*

See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301/15168)

In fairness, K&R were essentially describing the standard implementation of the standard I/O library at the time when the 1st Edition was written (1978), modernized sufficiently to be using function prototype notation in the 2nd Edition.  The original code was on pages 165-168 of the 1st Edition.

Even today, if you are *implementing* the standard library, you would use names starting with underscores precisely because they are reserved for use 'by the implementation'.  If you are not implementing the standard library, you do not use names starting with underscores because that uses the namespace reserved for the implementation.  Most people, most of the time, are not writing the standard library — most people should not be using leading underscores.