# Easier code in 8.5 K&R book, only logical operator instead bit operation and logical operator

Tags: c

In section 8.5, in fopen example, K&R write:

```
if ((fp->flag & (_READ | _EOF | _ERR )) != _READ)
```

But I see this easier:

```
if (fp->flag != _READ)
```

Is my code bad or K&R is simple obscure...
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [k&r fopen and fillbuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598201/kr-fopen-and-fillbuf)

Answer (score 2):

The bits of the `flag` member are assigned more meanings than just `_READ` (`01`), `_EOF` (`010`, which is octal for 8), and `_ERR` (`020`, 16). There are also `_WRITE` (`02`) and `_UNBUF` (`04`).

Kernighan and Ritchie’s code, `(fp->flag & (_READ | _EOF | _ERR )) != _READ`, is true if and only if `_READ` is clear, `_EOF` is set, or `_ERR` is set.

Your code, `fp->flag != _READ`, is true if and only if `_READ` is clear, `_EOF` is set, `_ERR` is set, `_WRITE` is set, or `_UNBUF` is set.

Thus, for example, if `_UNBUF` is set while `_READ` is set, `_EOF` is clear, and `_ERR` is clear, the Kernighan and Ritchie code will evaluate to false but your code will evaluate to true. The Kernighan and Ritchie code asks only about three flags and does not care about the other flags. Your code is affected by all the flags.

Comment: Thanks Eric, now I understand.