# C typedef linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, typedef

Supposed I have a struct with pointers to variables of the same type, for example for a simple linked list implementation.

Which of these two approaches is the most correct one?

EDIT: assume I have previously declared `typedef struct list_ list;`, otherwise Option 2 will not compile

Option 1:

```
typedef struct _list
{
    int num;
    struct _list *next;
} list;
```

Option 2:

```
typedef struct _list
{
    int num;
    list* next;
} list;
```

Both compile and work, so which should I use?

Comment: I don't even write `typedef`s for `struct`s; instead using `struct x` or `struct *x` everywhere - if the structure is not opaque there is not much sense in trying to hide the fact either.

Comment: Second option doesn't compile on GCC.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right, for the second option to compile the `typedef` must be declared first, I will edit the question accordingly

Comment: At file-level, names starting with underscore are reserved for the implementation in all name-spaces. You must not use them in application code. And the second variant is not valid C.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: `struct *x`?? You mean `struct x *`?!

Comment: @Olaf well, yes of course :D

Comment: You should copy/past **working/compilable** code. There are still typos!

Comment: Note that if example 2 has `typedef struct list_ list;`, then the pointer in `struct _list` is to a structure of a different type (a `struct list_`).  Don't use names starting with an underscore — most of them are reserved for the implementation.  If you need to know the details (which names starting with an underscore you can safely use), check out [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449181/), one amongst many questions which cover the topic.  The simple answer is 'none'!  That is over-simplistic, but not by much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no real 'correct' answer to this question; it's a matter of personal preference. As with all style issues, I would say the following:

- Be consistent
- If you are coding in a group, agree a style with the rest of the group.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another one:

```
typedef struct _list list;

struct _list {
    int num;
    list* next;
};
```

**Edit**
Both options presented in the question are valid, but I would prefer the first one. Option number 2 is a bit suspicious, as you use the `list` identifier *before* it actually got defined. However, compilers may accept such declaration, because it's sufficient for them to know the `next` member is a pointer to 'something', and they do not need to know at the point what actually 'something' is. That would be necessary later, when compiling expressions which make use of the `next` member, but then the meaning of `list` (namely, that it's an alias for `struct _list`) will be known.

For this reason, the two options are equivalent, and the choice is a matter of taste or habit.

The third option I present above is a bit different. It correctly declares `list` as a synonym for `struct _list` but does *not* define the `_list` structure. That allows you to publish prototypes of functions that use the type *without* publishing the type itself:

Suppose you implement a library to manage some container. A cont.h file might then look somewhat like this:

```
typedef struct _container Container;

Container *CreateContainer(void);
void DestroyContainer(Container *cont);
int AddDataToContainer(Container *cont, const char *data);
int PrintContainer(const Container *cont);
```

while details of implementation are hidden in a separate cont.c module:

```
#include "cont.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

struct _container {
    //  all members declarations
};

Container *CreateContainer(void)
{
    // create an object
    Container *cont = malloc(sizeof(Container));
    if(cont != NULL) {
        // initialize its members
        ;
    }

    // and return it (or NULL on malloc() failure
    return cont;
}

void DestroyContainer(Container *cont)
{
    // cleanup the container contents
    ;
    // dispose the container itself
    free(cont);
}

// ....
```

Comment: Ok, but what are the reasons to choose one over the other? Or is it all the same?

Comment: Generally a matter of preference.

Comment: @Frank Please see the edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use either one. They are essentially the same thing.