# Empty Declaration with Storage class specifier/Two or more data types in declaration specifiers

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, typedef, trie

I'm currently getting 2 errors when I try to compile my files with a makefile.

The following errors pop up and I'm not sure how to fix it:

- two or more data types in declaration specifiers
- empty declaration with storage class specifier does not redeclare tag

concerning this line:

```
typedef enum __bool__ bool;
```

The code for my header file supplied by the school for my assessment are as follows:

```
#ifndef _dict_h
#define _dict_h

#define VECSIZE ('z'-'a' + 1)

typedef char *word;
enum __bool__ { FALSE, TRUE };
typedef enum __bool__ bool;

typedef struct __tnode__  *Dict, TNode;
struct __tnode__ {
    Dict cvec[VECSIZE];         
    bool eow;                   
};

void newdict(Dict *dp);
void addword (const Dict r, const word w);
bool checkword (const Dict r, const word w);
void delword (const Dict r, const word w);
```

And for my C file which I'm currently writing up:

```
void newdict (Dict *dp) {
    *dp = NULL;
    dp = (Dict *)malloc(sizeof(Dict));
    if (dp) {
        int i;
        (*dp)->eow = FALSE;
        for (i = 0; i < VECSIZE; i++) {
            (*dp)->cvec[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
}

void addword (const Dict r, const word w) {
    int level;
    int length = strlen(w);
    int index;

    Dict pCrawl = r;

    for (level = 0; level < length; level++) {
        index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(w[level]);
        if (!pCrawl->cvec[index]) {
            newdict(&(pCrawl->cvec[index]));
        }
        pCrawl = pCrawl->cvec[index];
    }
    pCrawl->eow = TRUE;
}

bool checkword (const Dict r, const word w) {
    int level;
    int length = strlen(w);
    int index;

    Dict pCrawl = r;

    for (level = 0; level < length; level++) {
        index = CHAR_TO_INDEX(w[level]);
        if (!pCrawl->cvec[index]) {
            return false;
        }
        pCrawl = pCrawl->cvec[index];       
    }
    return(pCrawl != NULL && pCrawl->eow);

}
```

I'm relatively new to C so any tips related or not related to the errors would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First off, we'd appreciate you sharing full error messages. That makes it a lot easier for us to track down errors.

Comment: `bool` is defined in `<stdbool.h>` since C99. Chances are you use `<stdbool.h>` and the school-provided header file, thus causing a name clash. Try something different than `bool` as the new type name and see if that error disappears.

Comment: Note that you should not create function, variable or macro names that start with an underscore, in general. [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says (in part): — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301/15168)

Comment: You might need to let your school know that they've been treading on thin ice for a long time.\

Comment: You may need to run the C preprocessor on your code and study the output.  You'll need to create a minimal reproduction so you get to look at as few system headers as possible — they are apt to be big and hard to follow.  When you get to the lines causing the trouble in the compilation, you'll be able to see what the compiler sees, and it may be a lot clearer where the trouble is.