# reflect changes to both struct if changes are made to only one struct

Tags: c

I have the following structs where `access2` uses `ctx1` indirectly through `access1`. Suppose if I set the value of `val1` through `access2`, how can I make sure that `access1` also reflects the same changes as shown in `main()`?

```
typedef struct __ctx1{
   int val1;
   int val2;
}ctx1;

typedef struct __access1{
   int counts;
   ctx1 cx1;
}access1;

typedef struct __access2{
  int options;
  access1 base1;
}access2;


int main(){
 access2 *base2;
 base2->base1.cx1.val1 = 5;
 access1 *acc;
 printf("val1 %d\n",acc->cx1.val1);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use double-underscore prefix, those are reserved for the implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449181/what-does-double-underscore-const-mean-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do here, but `acc` is uninitialized.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I think his question may be what he's supposed to set it to.

Comment: Use pointers rather than embedding copies of structs within structs.

Comment: @Barmar, that's right, what should I do so that if one changes other should also reflect the same changes with respect to val1 and val2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `acc` to point to the address of that substructure:

```
access1 *acc = &(base2->base1);
```

You also never allocated space for `base2` to point to, it should be:

```
access2 *base2 = malloc(sizeof access2);
```