# How do strcat() and read() work with '\0' in C

Tags: c, null, pipe, strcat

here's my whole code first :

```
 1. #include <stdio.h>
 2. #include <stdlib.h>
 3. #include <unistd.h>
 4. #include <sys/wait.h>
 5. #include <string.h>
 6. int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 7.     int p[2]; // p[0]: file descriptor for read end of pipe
 8.               // p[1]: file descriptor for write end of pipe
 9.     if (pipe(p) < 0) exit(1);
 10.    int rc1 = fork();
 11.    if (rc1 < 0){ fprintf(stderr, "fork error\n"); }
 12.    else if (rc1 == 0){ write(p[1], "1st child output",
 13.                              sizeof("1st child output")); }
 14.    else{
 15.        int rc2 = fork();
 16.        if (rc2 < 0){ fprintf(stderr, "fork error\n"); }
 17.        else if (rc2 == 0){
 18.            printf("2st child output\n");
 19.            char *_1st_child_out;
 20.            read(p[0], _1st_child_out, sizeof("1st child output"));
 21.            strcat(_1st_child_out, ", AFTER PIPE YA FOOL");
 22.            printf("%s\n", _1st_child_out);
 23.        }
 24.    }
 25. }
```

if i initialize 19:13:

> char *_1st_child_out;

with a '\0' or NULL,
the string stays empty and 22:13:

> printf("%s\n", _1st_child_out);

prints nothing, so how do strcat() and read() work?
should i not insert any null terminators before invoking them?
what about garbage values?

Comment: `read(p[0], _1st_child_out, sizeof("1st child output"))` is reading into an uninitialized pointer, which is invalid.

Comment: it reads input from the file descriptor provided in p[0], (which gets written in the pipe() call), and stores what has been read (i.e. what has been written in the write() above) to the _1st_child_out  *char

Comment: I don't think the `pipe()` and `fork()` calls change anything -- could you reproduce the error with a smaller program?

Comment: @AhmedRehan: `_1st_child_out` is an uninitialized pointer. You can’t read anything into what it points to.

Comment: `pipe()` doesn't do anything with `\0`.

Comment: @Blacksilver 
as the code currently is, there isn't any errors, if i make the uninitialized char pointer "_1st_child_out" a NULL, nothing gets written or concatenated in it,
and is i'm not fully grasping the effect of pipe, write & read i'm not sure which is causing the error and eitherway i'd like to know how both handle this situation

Comment: @Ry-♦
Oh ok, sorry i get what you meant now, i misunderstood "reading into", that means i should initialize my pointer first right, but initializing with NULL alone doesn't allow further writing or appending to it with write() and strcat()

Comment: @EJP thanks for pointing that out, sorry, i meant read()

Comment: Note that you should not create function, variable or macro names that start with an underscore, in general. [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says (in part): — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301/15168)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few bugs in your code, here are the my observation.

**Case 1  :-** In your code you are calling `fork()` two times, pipe write end `p[1]` contains some data `1st child output` in first `fork()` `rc1`  process, but your code tried to read form `p[0]` in second `rc2` process.

you should check `read()` return value whether it's success or not or may be it's reading from wrong/uninitialized file descriptors. This

```
    char *_1st_child_out = NULL;
    /* for process rc2, p[0] contains nothing, so what read() will read from p[0] ?? */
    int ret = read(p[0], _1st_child_out, sizeof("1st child output"));
    if(ret == -1) {
          perror("read");
          /* error handling */
   }
```

Since data written into `p[1]` in `rc1` process, not in `rc2` process, but here when you tries to read from `p[0]` it gives you

> read: Bad address

**Case 2 :-** To overcome above problem one way is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int p[2]; // p[0]: file descriptor for read end of pipe
        // p[1]: file descriptor for write end of pipe
        if (pipe(p) < 0) exit(1);
        int rc1 = fork();
        if (rc1 < 0){ fprintf(stderr, "fork error\n"); }
        else if (rc1 == 0){
                write(p[1], "1st child output",sizeof("1st child output"));
        }
        else{
                char *_1st_child_out = NULL;

                /* read() will read from p[0] and store into _1st_child_out but _1st_child_out not holding any valid memory ? So it causes Undefined behavior */
                int ret = read(p[0], _1st_child_out, sizeof("1st child output"));
                if(ret == -1) {
                perror("read");
                /* error handling */
                }
                strcat(_1st_child_out, ", AFTER PIPE YA FOOL");
                printf("%s\n", _1st_child_out);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Here `_1st_child_out` is a pointer and pointers should have valid memory location. you can initialize with `NULL` which is `(void*)0`, that's valid but not with `\0` as it's just a single character.

But when you initialize `_1st_child_out` with `NULL` and read the data from `p[0]` & store into `_1st_child_out`, what it will store into it ? It causes segmentation fault and it's also **undefined behavior**.

So it's better to allocate memory dynamically for `_1st_child_out` and then call `read()` or create the stack allocated array like

```
char _1st_child_out[10];
```

Here is the sample working code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int p[2]; // p[0]: file descriptor for read end of pipe
        // p[1]: file descriptor for write end of pipe
        if (pipe(p) < 0) exit(1);
        int rc1 = fork();
        if (rc1 < 0){ fprintf(stderr, "fork error\n"); }
        else if (rc1 == 0){
                write(p[1], "1st child output",sizeof("1st child output"));
        }
        else{

                char *_1st_child_out = malloc(BYTE); /* define BYTE value as how much memory needed, and free the dynamically allocated memory once job is done */
                int ret = read(p[0], _1st_child_out, sizeof("1st child output"));
                if(ret == -1) {
                        perror("read");
                        /* error handling */
                }
                /* make sure _1st_child_out has enough memory space to concatenate */
                strcat(_1st_child_out, ", AFTER PIPE YA FOOL");
                printf("%s\n", _1st_child_out);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Note : Use `strncat()` instead of `strcat()`, reason you can find from manual page of `strcat()` https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat It says

> The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string,
>   overwriting the terminating null byte (`'\0'`) at
>          the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte.  The strings may not overlap, and the `dest`  string  must
>          have  enough space for the result.  If `dest` is not large enough, **program behavior is unpredictable**; **buffer over‐
>          runs are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs**.
>
> ```
>    The strncat() function is similar, except that
>
>    *  it will use at most n bytes from src; and
>
>    *  src does not need to be null-terminated if it contains n or more bytes.
>
>    As with `strcat()`, the resulting string in dest is always null-terminated.
> ```

Comment: what is the optimal way to create a pipe between two children of the same parent? (this was specifically asked in a book assignment)
And why might the read() be reading from a wrong/uninitialized file descriptor?
The first couple of google results never go in depth about these these functions, is there a specific documentation that goes over them more thoroughly?

Answer (score 1):

Your line 19 has a pointer that is not pointing to any allocated memory. Change it to a char array will fix the problem.

`char _1st_child_out[100];`

Also, for security, don't use `strcat`. All str function such as `strcpy` etc does not check destination boundary. They all have an `n` version. `strcat` should be replaced with `strncat`, which will take a third parameter to specify max length of cat so buffer overflow will not happen.

Answer (score 1):

`READ(2)` does not care about '\0', it does not care about the any value he reads.
`STRCAT(3)` will read and write (operations, not functions) from the '\0' at the end of the given `const char *src` pointer.

From what I'm seeing, `_1st_child_out` is an uninitialized pointer.
Semewhere in READ(2) there will be something as

`dest[i] = array_bytes[i];`

But here, your `char *_1st_child_out` is given a totaly "random" value and you will just write somewhere random in your memory, most of the time it will result in a Segmentation Fault, and your program will crash.

Then you need to take care about your use of `sizeof` operator here,
you gives him `"1st child output"` which will be interpreted as a `const char[]` in C and will replace `sizeof("1st child output")` by the value 17 (16 characters and the '\0').
You need to specify a type in it, or a variable.

For arrays, like `type array[x]`, `sizeof(array)` will be the same as `sizeof(type) * x`.

In order to fix your program, try creating a staticly allocated buffer like
`char _1st_child_out[x];` where 'x' is the size (in bytes) of the buffer.
Or try using `MALLOC(3)`.
Then fix your 3rd parameter of `READ(2)`.

When you'll use `STRCAT(3)`, you need to know that if the size of the given destination buffer is not long enough to contain `", AFTER PIPE YA FOOL"` your program have a huge chance of crashing.