# include file seems ignored

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'm sure I don't see something obvious, but here it is :

I've written a small tools.h file containing 2 macros I use in several files of my project :

```
#ifndef _TOOLS_H_
#define _TOOLS_H_


#define is_in_range(x, a, b) ((x) >= (a)) && ((x) < (b))

#define clamp(x, a, b)\
    (((x) < (a)) ? (a) : (((x) > (b)) ? (b) : (x)))

#endif
```

I added a `#include "tools.h"` in every source file using `clamp` and `is_in_range`, but they seem ignored at compilation.

For example,

```
C:/SGDK134/bin/gcc -m68000 -Wall -fno-builtin -Iinc -Isrc -Ires -IC:/SGDK134/inc -IC:/SGDK134/res -BC:/SGDK134/bin -O3 -fuse-linker-plugin -fno-web -fno-gcse -fno-unit-at-a-time -fomit-frame-pointer -flto -c src/camera.c -o out/src/camera.o
src/camera.c: In function 'camera_set_focus':
src/camera.c:130:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clamp' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 x = clamp(fix32ToInt(obj->x) - 128, 0, current_stage.pwidth - 320);
```

I have several others, one for each source file referring to `tools.h`.

And, of course, the compilation aborts:

```
C:/SGDK134/bin/gcc -BC:/SGDK134/bin -n -T C:/SGDK134/md.ld -nostdlib out/sega.o @out/cmd_ C:/SGDK134/lib/libmd.a C:/SGDK134/lib/libgcc.a -o out/rom.out
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\cczl66At.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
.text.startup+0x3ec): undefined reference to `clamp'
.text.startup+0x972): undefined reference to `clamp'
.text.startup+0x9c8): undefined reference to `clamp'
.text.startup+0xb5c): undefined reference to `is_in_range'
.text.startup+0xce0): undefined reference to `clamp'
make.exe": *** [out/rom.out] Error 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Note that you should not create function or variable names that start with an underscore, in general. [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says (in part): — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301/15168)

Comment: Why are you defining macros? Define functions and let the optimizing compiler take care of the rest. Unless you have concrete performance data proving this is necessary, it probably isn't.

Comment: I suggest using the `-H` option to GCC to report on which header files are included.  You may find that there is a different `tools.h` file that is being used.  Although I mentioned that `_TOOLS_H_` is not a good choice for a header guard macro (because it is reserved for the system to use), it probably isn't the immediate source of the trouble.

Comment: Put a `#error tools` on the first line of your header and make sure that you're actually including *that* tools.h and not some other tools.h.

Comment: try to replace your include protection by `#pragma once` in case some other header uses the same `_TOOLS_H_` identifier.

Comment: @user3386109 There's also the tried and true method of just mashing in sdhfusdfbgdrubguerwbtwebterte and expecting a compiler error!

Comment: @tadman While an effective technique, I can never manage to get the spelling down without looking it up.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: True, but I find `ZaphodBeeblebroxLovesPanGalacticGargleBlasters` quite effective too, and it's easier to remember the spelling of that!

Comment: Your is_in_range macro is wrong, you need paranethesis around the whole macro as well.

Comment: user3386109 is right : there's indeed a tools.h in the library I'm using !

Comment: And thanks Fredrik for pointing it, and others for valuable tips (-H, #pragma once and provoking an error).

Comment: "What am I missing?" --> Post lacks the code for `src/camera.c` to diagnose the issue.  Review [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

The answer was given by user3386109 : there was a file named `tools.h` in the library I was using.