# Bison/Lex segfaults on x86 but runs on arm

Tags: c, bison, cpu-architecture, lex

I have a problem described in the title. I have an Edify language parser that runs without errors when I building it on arm but fails when I try to use it with x86. I traced segfault to yy_scan_bytes function, more precisely to [this code](https://github.com/twaik/edify_x86_failing_code/blob/master/lex.yy.c#L1703):

```
YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_bytes  (yyconst char * yybytes, int  _yybytes_len ) {
YY_BUFFER_STATE b;
char * buf;
yy_size_t n;
int i;
/* Get memory for full buffer, including space for trailing EOB's. */
n = _yybytes_len + 2;
buf = (char *) yyalloc(n  );

if ( ! buf ) {
  YY_FATAL_ERROR( "out of dynamic memory in yy_scan_bytes()" );
}

for ( i = 0; i < _yybytes_len; ++i ) {
  buf[i] = yybytes[i]; // <==========
}
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/twaik/edify_x86_failing_code
I've got it from AROMA Installer source.
That's everything I discovered after debug. Thanks.

Comment: To have a segfault here, `[i]` is out-of-bounds for either `buf` or `yybytes`.  Have you inspected these strings during processing?   This file is genereated by the lexical analyser maker `lex` (or `flex`).  Have you tried regenerating this file?  Theoretically it shouldn't have issues, but obviously it does.

Comment: Regenerating does not affect it, it still segfaults. I am using function

int parse_string(const char* str, Expr** root, int* error_count) {
    yy_switch_to_buffer(yy_scan_string(str));
    return yyparse(root, error_count);
} 
to measure length of string. But it fails on yy_scan_string function.

Comment: Do you have access to another version of flex/lex etc. ?

Comment: You should add `-Wall` to the compile command in your Makefile. You don't seem to be declaring the flex buffer functions anywhere. `-ggdb` would help you debug, too.

Comment: Note that you should not create function, variable or macro names that start with an underscore, in general. [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says (in part): — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301/15168)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The quoted snippet is part of the code generated by flex, so you should take that up with the flex authors and not with OP, who is entirely innocent. :) In any case, you're allowed to use a local (not file-scope) name which starts with a single underscore followed by a lower case letter, so I think the flex authors are also working within the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to build your code gives me these errors:

> ```
> main.c: In function ‘parse_string’:
> main.c:27:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yy_switch_to_buffer’ [-W
> implicit-function-declaration]
>      yy_switch_to_buffer(yy_scan_string(str));
>      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> main.c:27:25: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yy_scan_string’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>      yy_switch_to_buffer(yy_scan_string(str));
> ```

That means that the compiler assumes that `yy_switch_to_buffer()` and `yy_scan_string()` return an `int`, as it does for all functions that are not declared before use (as per the c89 standard). But that is not the case (the first returns `void`, and the second a pointer (`YY_BUFFER_STATE`)). Notice that on x86_64, the size of a pointer is **not** the same as the size of an `int`.

Adding some band-aid prototypes like

```
void yy_switch_to_buffer(void*);
void *yy_scan_string(const char*);
```

to `main.c`, before their use in `parse_string()` may stop the segfaulting.

A better fix would be to arrange in the Makefile that the lexer be run with the `--header-file=lex-header.h` option, and then include `lex-header.h` from `main.c`. Or even better, wrap all lex-specific code in some simple functions, and put the prototypes of those functions in a header included from both `main.c` and the `*.l` file.

Comment: Ok. For now edify tests passes. But parsing real script is starting with `line 1 col 1: syntax error, unexpected BAD, expecting IF or STRING or '!' or '('` error. But not on arm. Any ideas?

Comment: that's hard to tell without the "real script".

Comment: You can use that one for testing https://github.com/amarullz/AROMA-Installer/blob/master/assets/META-INF/com/google/android/aroma-config

Comment: @twaik: that script starts with a BOM, as you can see from `hd aroma-config|head -n1` (which prints `00000000  ef bb bf 23 23 23 20 4c  49 43 45 4e 53 45 3a 0a  |...### LICENSE:.|`). I suppose you (or somebody) created the file on Windows.

Comment: and the program only reads 8191 bytes (or less) from the file, out of 50002.

Comment: @mosvy: That's true, but it fails on the first one :) There are other issues, too.

Comment: and it doesn't recognize a lot of functions/keywords, and in main() it will try to dump & evaluate the `root` variable, even if yyparse() failed and didn't set it at all.

Comment: Thank you guys. Looks like BOM is the exact problem. That is just the test snippet that tries to use syntax analyzer from the target project.

Comment: AROMA Installer has BOM skipper and I don't know why it is not working on x86. `    if ((script_data[0] == 0xEF) &&
        (script_data[1] == 0xBB) &&
        (script_data[2] == 0xBF)) {
      script_data += 3;}
`

Comment: For some reason script_data[0,1,2] was seen as "0xFFFFFFEF 0xFFFFFFBB 0xFFFFFFBF", not "0xEF 0xBB 0xBF" as expected. I've added "& 0xFF" to the byte checking code and now everything is working.

Comment: That's because you `script_data` was signed chars, and they were sign-extended when promoted to `int` for the sake of comparing them to `0xEF`, etc. You can reproduce it with `char *x = "\xef"; printf("%d %d\n", x[0] == 0xef, x[0] == '\xef');`.

Comment: btw, the `-Wtype-limits` option may help. Use it.