# Array declaration in header file

Tags: c, arrays, header

I have seen a code where there was declared a char array in a header file and the header was included in two files.

```
// header
char lookup[255];
```

I thought there should be some linker error for two definitions of array of the same name and I should be declare it and define it in a .c file and put extern in the header.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow what your question is here--are you asking why there was no linker error as you expected?

Comment: yes, if i compile it into binary, i dont get any error and it seems both .c files use the same char array.

Comment: See the discussion of 'the common extension' in [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)  You're right; strict standard conformance would expect an error, but the standard itself notes that it is a 'common extension' in C11 [§J.5.11 Multiple external definitions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.11).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You would hope for at least a warning if compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: It's tough for a single TU (translation unit) to identify problems which are only a problem when multiple TUs are linked together. Sadly, it not easy for the compiler to diagnose the issue at all.  Now, if you asked for a loader/linker option to identify it, then yes — it might be useful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put any actual data or code into the header files. There are some exceptions like static inline functions, but as rule of thumb: in header files only declarations and types, in `.c` files definitions

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will compile each .c file independently, not knowing that it was already included in another file. But you will get a linker error as soon as you try to link the compiled object files together.

With gcc, the following works:

```
gcc -c include1.cpp include2.cpp
```

But linking fails:

```
gcc -o include include1.o include2.o
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: include2.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `lookup'; include1.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The question isn't so worried about it being included twice in the same translation unit, but rather being included by two different .c files.

Comment: OT: identifiers beginning with and underscore should be avoided since they are reserved.

Comment: my question is rather how come it's possible that it is included in two different .c files and compiles just fine.

Comment: @Osiris I believe it is only reserved if the leading underscore is followed by a second underscore or a capital letter.  In this case, it was followed by a capital, so it was indeed reserved.

Comment: Note that by compiling `.cpp` files, you've used the C++ rules, one of which is the ODR (one definition rule).  On some systems (Linux for example), there's a linker option `-Wl,-relax` that might allow it to link.  However, using C++ when answering a C question isn't all that helpful.

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301)