# Compiler error with struct definition in header file

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I keep getting a compiler issue when trying to use a `struct` I defined in a header file.

I have two files: `main.c`:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include "node.h"

     int main(){
         struct NODE node;
         node.data = 5;
         printf("%d\n", node.data);
         return 0;
     }
```

as well as `node.h`:

```
#ifndef NODE
#define NODE
    struct NODE{
        int data;
        struct NODE *next;
    };

#endif
```

I was writing a small program to practice some modular programming in C, but I've been getting the following compiler error:

```
node.h:5:21: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘*’ token
         struct NODE *next;
                     ^
```

I got the `main.c` to compile and do what I would like it to do when I define the `struct` directly in the file `main.c`, but for some reason it won't work if I place the definition in a header file and then try to include it in `main.c`. It's very frustrating, and I'm sure it's a minor thing, but could someone please tell me why this isn't working? From what I've been reading, I should be able to do this, no?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Change your include guard to something like `NODE_H_`.

Comment: @StoryTeller why should changing the name in the include guard help this code compile?

Comment: Because `#define NODE` means "replace any occurrence of the token`NODE` by nothing".  For a header file `header.h`, normal conventions for the header guard include `HEADER_H` or `HEADER_H_INCLUDED` — and you'll see system headers using leading underscores, but they're required to do that and you're required NOT to do that.

Comment: Because your struct has the same name as the your include guard `#define`, so the preprocessor is expanding it into an empty string.

Comment: As my fellows explained, this is why the header definition needs to be more unique than others. Always define your headers with unique suffix such as ```_H_``` or whatever you like.

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301)

Answer (score 6):

The preprocessor is expanding `NODE` to nothing because you've defined it with a macro. Change your header file to look like this:

```c
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
    struct NODE{
        int data;
        struct NODE *next;
    };

#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You defined a macro NODE as nothing. From that point on, every NODE in your source code is replaced with nothing. So your header file is actually:

```
struct{
    int data;
    struct *next;
};
```

That should answer your question why changing the include guard from NODE to NODE_H fixes it.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOH I see now. It was a name collision! works now, thanks!