# How to fix undefined reference linker errors when static linking archive with gcc target_clones function multi-versioning

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, simd

I am using the target_clones GCC attribute for run-time optimized SIMD versions of several functions, some declared static and others used by other objects in the same static library. The latter have declarations, with the target_clones attribute, in a header file. All of the objects build fine and are assembled into a static archive with ar. The final application linking stage fails though when including the static archive, with undefined reference errors to the versioned symbols for the library public functions.

UPDATE: Added a gcc bug report, in case that is what this is: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91664

I created a test application which illustrates this problem here https://github.com/elementgreen/fmv-test
It has 3 make targets. The first one "make works" just compiles the test app all in one step from .c files. The second "make also_works" compiles each .c file into object .o files and then links those with gcc -o. The third target "make borken" does not work and illustrates the problem. Each .c file is compiled into .o object files, then a static archive is created with ar, then gcc is used to link the static archive into the final application.

Here are the contents of the test application I put on github:

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "fmv-test.h"

#define ARRAY_SIZE    100000

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  double *dArray;

  dArray = malloc (ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof (double));
  memset (dArray, 0, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof (double));

  fmv_test (dArray, ARRAY_SIZE);

  return 0;
}
```

fmv-test.h:

```
#ifndef __FMV_TEST_H__
#define __FMV_TEST_H__

#define SIMD_CLONE              __attribute__ ((__target_clones__ ("avx2","avx","sse4.1","sse2","default")))

double fmv_test (double *dArray, int size) SIMD_CLONE;

#endif
```

fmv-test.c:

```
#include "fmv-test.h"

static void internal_func (double *dArray, int size) SIMD_CLONE;

double
fmv_test (double *dArray, int size)
{
  double result;
  int i;

  internal_func (dArray, size);

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    result += dArray[i];

  return result;
}

static void
internal_func (double *dArray, int size)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    dArray[i] += 1.0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
works:
        @echo "This works"
        gcc -o fmv-test fmv-test.c main.c

also_works:
        @echo "This also works"
        gcc -c fmv-test.c
        gcc -c main.c
        gcc -o fmv-test fmv-test.o main.o

borken:
        @echo "This doesn't work"
        gcc -c fmv-test.c
        gcc -c main.c
        ar cr fmv-test.a fmv-test.o main.o
        gcc -o fmv-test-borken fmv-test.a
```

Linking a static archive with gcc function multi-versioning should work. Instead it fails with the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: fmv-test.a(main.o): in function `fmv_test':
main.c:(.text.fmv_test.resolver[fmv_test.resolver]+0x1f): undefined reference to `fmv_test.avx2.0'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text.fmv_test.resolver[fmv_test.resolver]+0x3b): undefined reference to `fmv_test.avx.1'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text.fmv_test.resolver[fmv_test.resolver]+0x57): undefined reference to `fmv_test.sse4_1.2'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text.fmv_test.resolver[fmv_test.resolver]+0x71): undefined reference to `fmv_test.sse2.3'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text.fmv_test.resolver[fmv_test.resolver]+0x7a): undefined reference to `fmv_test.default.4'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems the object files end up with different numbered endings on the various symbols, but these still manage to link up with the "also_works" target, so I don't think that is the problem (see below output from objdump). Is this a bug in gcc? I'm using version 8.3.0 on Ubuntu 19.04.

```sh
objdump -t fmv-test.o | grep fmv_test
```

```
0000000000000000 l     F .text  0000000000000062 fmv_test.default.9
0000000000000239 l     F .text  0000000000000062 fmv_test.avx2.4
000000000000029b l     F .text  0000000000000062 fmv_test.avx.5
00000000000002fd l     F .text  0000000000000062 fmv_test.sse4_1.6
000000000000035f l     F .text  0000000000000062 fmv_test.sse2.7
0000000000000000 l    d  .text.fmv_test.resolver    0000000000000000 .text.fmv_test.resolver
00000000000003c1 g   i   .text  0000000000000080 internal_func._GLOBAL___fmv_test.ifunc
0000000000000000  w    F .text.fmv_test.resolver    0000000000000080 fmv_test.resolver
0000000000000000 g   i   .text.fmv_test.resolver    0000000000000080 fmv_test
```

```sh
objdump -t main.o | grep fmv_test
```

```
0000000000000000 l    d  .text.fmv_test.resolver    0000000000000000 .text.fmv_test.resolver
0000000000000000 g   i   .text.fmv_test.resolver    0000000000000080 fmv_test
0000000000000000  w    F .text.fmv_test.resolver    0000000000000080 fmv_test.resolver
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 fmv_test.avx2.0
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 fmv_test.avx.1
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 fmv_test.sse4_1.2
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 fmv_test.sse2.3
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 fmv_test.default.4
```

Comment: You don't normally put a file with `main()` into a library (there are exceptions, but they're rare and mostly obsolescent).  However, that shouldn't stop it working.

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301)

Comment: Have you tried replacing `gcc` with `gcc -v`, at least on the linking commands in the makefile?  That would show you differences in how the linker is invoked, which might tell you about why two work and one does not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your comments. I understand that main() does not normally go in a library. This is just a small demonstration program, not the actual one where I originally encountered the issue. Also in regards to the double underscore.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have seen copious uses of _ _ FILE_H _ _ in header files (where FILE is the name of the file). Guess that doesn't mean it is "proper" though, but never had a problem with it, except occasional collisions with other non-system headers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I ran the link stage with -v and compared them with a diff tool. Only differences were .o files vs .a archive and the output file name. Does seem like it points to a linker related issue though.

Comment: System headers are required to use a name reserved for the implementation so as not to tread on the namespace reserved for users (programmers).  People frequently copy `__FILE_H__` or similar because they've seen it in system headers, not realizing that system headers work under different rules.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  If you remove (comment out temporarily) the SIMD clones directives, does anything change?  I haven't played with that sort of stuff.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, if I remove the target_clones attribute it links fine. Perhaps notable is I did a dump of the archive with nm and it shows that the clone functions are local symbols to the object file and they don't end up in the archive symbol index. If I remove the attribute, it shows up as a global symbol and gets included in the index. This could be a hint.