# Do types that begin with double underscore mean emulated type?

Tags: c, x86, floating-point

There is `long double` type for 80bit floating point, x87 extantion has instructions to work with this data type.

I know that there is `__float128` and basic operations with this type is emulated by compiler. But there is no need to emulate 80bit floating point operations. What is the purpose of `__float80` then?

I guess that there are some architectures that has no 80bit floating point data type, so `__float80` is like crossplatform type. If CPU able to work with 80bit fp then `long double` means same as `__float80`. If not then `long double` doesnt exist or refers to something else and compiler emulates 80bit fp operations so only `__float80` can be used to represent 80bit floationg point.

Am i right? Can u show me some examples?

Comment: You should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301)

Answer (score 5):

The double underscore indicates that the identifier is reserved for use by the implementation of C.

C11 standard **[7.1.3: Reserved Identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3)**

> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>     underscore are always reserved for any use.
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

Basically, it's a name-space reserved to avoid conflicts with identifiers created for general use.  The implementation can make sure it doesn't clobber its own identifiers, and as long as your program doesn't make use of the reserved identifier-space starting with double underscores (or underscore followed by capital letter) there will be no conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

No, `__` doesn't mean emulated, it means not one of the types from the ISO C standard.  Implementations don't want to pollute the global namespace with names like `float80` so they use names like `__float80` and `__int128`, because ISO C reserves double-underscore names for use by the implementation.

I'd guess that `__float80` gives you access to 80-bit float even when compiling for the MS Windows ABI where `long double` is the same format as `double`.  (IEEE binary64).

**You can think of `__float80` and `__float128` as an implementation-specific equivalents to `int64_t` instead of `long` or `long long`.**  On platforms that have native 80-bit FP, `__float80` doesn't need to be emulated.

On other targets, `__float80` might not be supported at all.