# How to access GCC -Dmacro?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

The question is as the title, I'm compiling a quite big code and want to have a debug option only when compiled with such option.

I'm using make to compile and I add the compile option on my debug rule:

```
debug: main
$(eval CFLAGS := -D_DEBUG_)
```

What I could not do was use this `_DEBUG_` macro inside the code to then print some debug info.

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449181)

Comment: What do you mean by "I could not do"? Did the compiler issue an error? Please always include the actual system message(s) of your problem as described in [MCVE].

Answer (score 4):

Passing `-Dmacro` to a compiler is equivalent to defining this symbol in the code:

```
#define macro
```

So "using" it in the code is similar as well - you can use preprocessor conditional directives:

```
#ifdef macro
// Your conditional code
#endif
```

(in your specific case the symbol  name is `_DEBUG_`)