# Macro definition causing error during composition

Tags: c++, c, macros

I am trying to get the macro to print out the file name followed by the line number and then the print message, here is how I do this normally, and it works but it prints out the entire file path to the file:

```
#define TESTER1(...) printf(ANSI_COLOR_BOLD_GREEN "LOG::" __FILE__ ":" STR(__LINE__) "\t" ANSI_COLOR_RESET ANSI_COLOR_GREEN __VA_ARGS__); printf(ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n")
```

this works, but the file path is way too long:
Example output:

```
C:\Users\Work\Documents\CastEngine\CastDriver\src\main.cpp:18: Example
```

What I want the output to be is the following:

```
main.cpp:18: Example
```

So here is the macro for that:

```
#define __FILENAME__ (strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__)
#define TESTER2(...) printf(ANSI_COLOR_BOLD_GREEN "LOG::" __FILENAME__ ":" STR(__LINE__) "\t" ANSI_COLOR_RESET ANSI_COLOR_GREEN __VA_ARGS__); printf(ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n")
```

I know that `__FILENAME__` works as intended because without defining TESTER2, I use this code:

```
printf("%s:%d", __FILENAME__, __LINE__);
```

and the output is exactly what I want: `main.cpp:19`

But when I add the TESTER2 define from above, it gives me the following error:

```
error: expression cannot be used as a function
 #define __FILENAME__ (strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '\\') + 1 : __FILE__)
                                                                                       ^
C:\Users\Work\Documents\CastEngine\CastDriver\src\main.cpp:11:59: note: in expansion of macro '__FILENAME__'
 #define TESTER2(...) printf(ANSI_COLOR_BOLD_GREEN "LOG::" __FILENAME__ ":" STR(__LINE__) "\t" ANSI_COLOR_RESET ANSI_COLOR_GREEN __VA_ARGS__); printf(ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n")
                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Work\Documents\CastEngine\CastDriver\src\main.cpp:20:5: note: in expansion of macro 'TESTER2'
     TESTER2("Hello\n");
```

I really have no idea how to fix this; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: String concatenation only works for string literals (`__FILE__` expands into a literal), you can't concatenate strings with expressions.

Comment: You are not allowed to create name with double underscores.  Those names are reserved for your implementation.

Comment: @Barmar, is there a way to turn its output into a literal while maintaining the one liner macro?

Comment: Of course not. Literals exist at compile time, functions are called at run time.

Comment: @Barmar so is there no way to accomplish this?

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449181)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more than one consecutive *`string literals`* and compiler will see them as one.

Example:

```
printf("He" "llo" "wo" "rld.");
```

But in your macro  `__FILENAME__` expands to the `strrchr` call + ternary operation and the result of it is not the *`string literal`* - thus syntax error.

```
#define TESTER2(...) printf(ANSI_COLOR_BOLD_GREEN "LOG::%s" ":" STR(__LINE__) "\t" ANSI_COLOR_RESET ANSI_COLOR_GREEN __VA_ARGS__, __FILENAME__); printf(ANSI_COLOR_RESET "\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always just use a function to clean it up.

```
printf("%s:%d",
       absl::StripPrefix(__FILENAME__, "C:\Users\Work\Documents\CastEngine\CastDriver\"),
       __LINE__);
```

Comment: This is missing all the other stuff that the `TESTER2()` macro is trying to print.

Comment: @Barmar: It seems relatively trivial to add all the other stuff?

Comment: You think so? Show how to do it. Remember that it's a variadic macro that's expanding into another call to `printf()`