# Unable to find documentation for __c11_atomic_load

Tags: c, assembly

I saw following function in the code:

```
__c11_atomic_load()
```

Where could be this function documentation. So far I have seen only documentation for:

```
atomic_load()
```

Comment: That's a compiler specific function (and probably intended for internal use only)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does double underscore ( \_\_const) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449181/what-does-double-underscore-const-mean-in-c)

Comment: So, no, you probably will not find documentation.  And that's ok, because you almost surely should not be calling that function.

Comment: See [this page](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html).