# empty char array, the ways I check it are the same?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, null-pointer, inequality

I have a char array and I want to check if it is null.

```
if(_char_array[0] != '\0') {...}
```

is the same as

```
if(_char_array != '\0') {...}
```

thanks

Comment: No, that cannot possibly do the same. One checks a single element of the array, the other compares the address

Comment: An array can't be null

Comment: Using `'\0'` as a null pointer is aconventional at best and confusing and misleading at worst.  Use `NULL` or `0` when you are comparing a pointer for null-ness.

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449181)

Comment: No, not the same. The first checks if the first char in the array is non-zero (i.e. the "string" is _not_ empty). The second checks if the array _address_ is non-zero (i.e. _not_ `NULL`). It is better written as `if (_char_array != NULL)`. It is more usual to do this if we have: `char *_char_array;` (vs. `char _char_array[1];`). The latter is still valid to do. And, it makes sense in _rare_ circumstances (e.g. we're in a standalone environment like a kernel and want to know if the array is loaded at address 0).

Answer (score 1):

This if statement

```
if(_char_array[0] != '\0') {...}
```

checks whether a character array contains a non-empty string.

In fact there are compared two integers: the first character of the array  `_char_array` promoted to the type `int` and the integer character constant `'\0'` that has the type `int`.

The statement can be rewritten also like

```
if( _char_array[0] ) {...}
```

or

```
if( *_char_array ) {...}
```

This if statement

```
if(_char_array != '\0') {...}
```

does not make a sense because any array occupies a memory extent. So converted to a pointer to its first element it can not be a null pointer.

That is in this statement there are compared a pointer to the first element of the array due to the implicit conversion of the array to a pointer to its first element and a null pointer constant.

If `_char_array` is initially declared as a pointer then the above if statement checks whether the pointer is not a null pointer.

The statement can be rewritten like

```
if( _char_array ) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first `if` statement you were checking whether the first element of `_char_array` is `0` or not, whereas in the second `if` statement you were checking address of `_char_array` to be `0` or not.

---

If the address is `0` then there would be 2 cases:

##### CASE 1

```c
char *_char_array = NULL;
```

##### CASE 2

```c
char *_char_array = malloc(<any_size>); // but malloc failed and returned `NULL`
```

---

**NOTE: Statically allocated arrays never have an address of `0`.**

Comment: No, static arrays _can_ have an address of 0. It's just not usual for most userspace programs. The zero page is mapped protected by the OS to trap null pointer dereferences as a _convenience_ to the app programmer. However, in an embedded system, on some arches, the interrupt vector table is placed at (hardwired to) location 0. So, we might have: `typedef void (*isr_entry)(void); isr_entry isr_table[256];` and the address of `isr_table` would be 0 (set by a linker script).

Answer (score 0):

An array name is not a pointer, but an identifier for a variable of type array, which is implicitly converted to a pointer to the element type.
These two are not the same at all, the array will always have value.

Answer (score 0):

While the syntax only differs by 3 characters, these do **very different things** once compiled.

##### `if(_char_array[0] != '\0')`

This checks if the value at index 0 within `_char_array` is not equal to 0.

1. `_char_array[0]`
   This retrieves the first element in the array as a `char`
2. `(_char_array[0]) != '\0'`
   This is resolved to a `bool`; it is `true` when the `char` from step 1 is not equal to 0.
3. `if (...)`
   This one is obvious, we check if the `bool` from step 2 is `true`.

##### `if(_char_array != '\0')`

This checks if `_char_array` is not equal to 0.

1. `_char_array`
   This represents the **entire array**.
   It is rare to see this syntax unless the array was declared with `char*` instead of `char[]`, in which case it is equivalent to `!= 0` or `!= NULL` since `'\0'` is the char literal for 0.
2. `(_char_array) != '\0'`
   This resolves to a `bool` that is `true` when the entire char array from step 1 is not equal to 0.
3. Same as above, we evaluate the `bool` from step 2.

##### Additionally

To echo [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s comment, don't get in the habit of starting names in C or C++ with a leading underscore `_`.
They're reserved by the standard so doing this is usually considered **undefined behaviour**, as it can cause namespace collisions if you try to use a different compiler, or even a different version of the same compiler.