# How can I fix an forward declaration warning in a structure

Tags: c, struct

I have several structures, and I keep getting a warning message. I've been trying for several hours to kick it out, but I can't.
I would really appreciate the help.

This is the Student struct in the `Student.h` header:

```
   #ifndef __STUDENT_H__
   #define __STUDENT_H__
   
   #include "Teacher.h"
   #include "ClassRoom.h"
   struct Teacher;
   struct ClassRoom;

   typedef struct {
       char * name;
       struct ClassRoom *myClassRoom;
       struct Teacher *myTeachers[3];
   } Student;

   void setTeacherDynamic(struct Teacher *t, struct Teacher* tt);
```

and this is the `Student.c` source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Teacher.h"
#include "Student.h"

struct Teacher;

void setTeacherDynamic(Teacher *t, Teacher* tt)
{
    strcpy(t->name, tt->name);

    t->myClass = NULL;

}
```

The warning message is:
[image]
The problem is with the function setTeacherDynamic(), and I don't know how to fix it.

The `Teacher` struct:

[image]

and this is when I'm calling to the function, also in `Student.c`

[image]

Comment: when im removing it, the warnings are still exist :(

Comment: The error message is clear,  your formal parameters are different with declaration. Check your declaration and formal parameters.

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449181)

Comment: You see the `__STUDENT_H__` notation in system headers because they _must_ use that notation.  You should not use that notation in your headers because it is reserved for the system to use.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems:

The first is that since you have forward declarations in `Student.h` you don't need to include `Teacher.h` or `ClassRoom.h`. And in the source file `Student.c` you can remove the forward declaration you have.

The second problem is that you don't actually have a `struct Teacher`. You have a `Teacher` type-alias for an *anonymous* structure. You should declare the actual structure for the forward declarations to work:

```
typedef struct Teacher { ... } Teacher;
```

You should do these changes for all your source and header files.

Comment: It actually works! am I suppose to remove the included from "Student.c" too?

Comment: @Bubi No, keep the includes in the source file.

Comment: In addition, I wanted to ask, why did I have to define the teacher like that?
In addition, the way I happen to the function and do the casting to "Struct student *, is it still correct in your opinion?

Comment: @Bubi If you don't give a name to the structure then it doesn't have a name. If a structure doesn't have a name, then it's of course not possible to use it anywhere, like in a forward declaration. Note that `struct Teacher` and `Teacher` are two *aliases* for the same structure, but they are still different. You cant forward declare a type-aliased structure without the structure name.

Comment: So why doesn't the compiler force me to write like this even for, say, a student's structure?

Comment: @Bubi Because it's not always needed. Sometimes anonymous structures are useful. When doing forward declarations they can't be used though.

Comment: So, if i got another struct, that include 2 pointer, "ClassRoom" - student, teacher, How do you suggest to do it?