# what't the reason when implicit declaration of function

Tags: c

Why does the return value of the function change when the number of bytes of `malloc` is large?

func.c:

```cpp
#include "func.h"

int *func()
{
    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(100000000);
    printf("ptr in func is %p \n", ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

func.h:

```cpp
#ifndef _FUNC_H
#define _FUNC_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//int *func();
#endif
```

main.c

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int *ptr = func();
    printf("ptr is %p \n", ptr);
}
```

compilation and run:

```bash
gcc -g main.c func.c -o main
```

the compilation result is:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘func’; did you mean ‘putc’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  int* ptr = func();
             ^~~~
             putc
main.c:7:13: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

run result:

```bash
ptr in func is 0x7f557ea88010
ptr is 0x7ea88010
```

Why does the function return the same value when the number of bytes of `malloc` is small?

func.c

```cpp
#include "func.h"

int *func()
{
    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(100);
    ptrintf("ptr in func is %p \n", ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

run result:

```
ptr in func is 0x17af2a0
ptr is 0x17af2a0
```

Can you tell me why?
I want to know what exactly caused it?

Comment: Please don't link to images of your code but cpy the code properly firmatted into your question

Comment: ok, I don't know much about it, i will show my code

Comment: @DaWang _" Why does the function return the same value when the number of bytes of malloc is small"_? You cannot predict what value `malloc` returns and you should't care about it. It depends on the implementation. If you really want to know, look at the source code of malloc of your platform (actually don't, it's way beyond your scope for the moment).

Comment: Any particular reason why the declaration in func.h is commented out?

Comment: No particular reason, just want to repeat the work encountered this problem.

Comment: You commented out the declaration of `func` here `//int* func();`. Then you're using the undeclared `func` here: `int* ptr = func();` hence the warning (which BTW should be considered as an error). Consider all warnings containing the word "implicit" as an error.

Comment: I not only want to know how to solve, but also want to know what caused the return of the address inconsistency problem.

Comment: Always the same. https://godbolt.org/z/T1dKo9zYf

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449181)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're obviously working on 64 bit system with `sizeof(int *) == 8` and `sizeof(int) == 4`.
Now when the function prototype is missing ("implicit declaration") the compiler assumes that `func()` returns `int` and so when you call `int *ptr = func()` only 4 bytes (`sizeof(int)`) of the return value are used, interpreted as `int` and cast back to `int *`. That results in the wrong `ptr` in the first example.

Int the second example, **by chance** the pointer value is smaller so it fits completely in 4 bytes and after being cast back, the result ist the same pointer again.
Nevertheless it's Undefined Behaviour and you should **really always** treat the warning "implicit declaration" as an error and provide all necessary prototypes.

Comment: But I didn't give you a prototype, so why is it possible to find the func function that needs to be run when it's running?

Comment: @DaWang without the prototype the compiler wrongly assumes that the function as been declared `int func();` and it emits a warning that is actually an error (yes, it's weird, it for historical reasons). As already mentioned, consider warnings containing the word "implicit" as errors.

Comment: Well the function exists and so the linker can produce an executable. And the compiler for historical reasons assumes `int func();` (function with unknown parameters returning int) if he sees a call to a function that's not declared.

Comment: Note that "no prototype before calling" is only valid in C90 (not in C99, not in any later version of the standard).   The OP should be compiling to at least C99 (almost 21st Century C), preferably C11 or C18.  (It's a bit too soon to be using C23 for production work.). The OP needs to use more stringent compiler warnings too — preferably something like `-Werror -Wall -Wextra` as a starting point if the compiler is GCC or Clang (I'd add a few more, but that's a reasonable start).

Answer (score 3):

You must declare functions before you use them.

**Corrected func.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>   // put includes you use in the .c file
#include <stdlib.h>  // put includes you use in the .c file
#include "func.h"

int* func(void)  // put void, so the compiler knows there are no
                 // arguments
{
   int* ptr = malloc(100000000);   // remove the (int*) cast, it's
                                   // not wrong, but useless
   printf("ptr in func is %p \n", ptr);
   return ptr;
}
```

**Corrected func.h:**

```
#ifndef _FUNC_H
#define _FUNC_H
// remove this (not wrong but bad practice) #include <stdio.h>
// remove this (not wrong but bad practice) #include <stdlib.h>

int* func(void);   // uncomment this and put void, so the compiler 
                   // knows there are no arguments

#endif
```

**Corrected main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>   // put includes you use in the .c file
#include "func.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int* ptr = func();
    printf("ptr is %p \n", ptr);
}
```

---

Following happens when you don't declare `func` prior to using it:

```
int* ptr = func();
```

As `func()` has not been declared, the compiler assumes (wrongly) that `func` returns an `int` (it actually returns a pointer to `int`). The function is called, the returned pointer in converted into an `int` possibly truncating the value from 64 bits to 32 bis (it depends on the platform).

If the returned address fits into 32 bits (which may be the case on certain platforms for small allocations), no truncation takes place.

Comment: Thank you for the correction to my header file