# What is this kind of variable/data type called in C?

Tags: c

In the following code snippet

```c
typedef enum {EVENT1, EVENT2} event_t;

typedef struct _params params_t;
typedef struct {int i; int j;} params_event1_t;
typedef struct {int i; float f;} params_event2_t;

void event_handler(event_t event, params_t *params)
{
    if (event == EVENT1)
    {
        params_event1_t *p;
        p = (params_event1_t *)params;
        ...
    }
    else if (event == EVENT2)
    {
        params_event2_t *p;
        p = (params_event2_t *)params;
        ...
    }
}
```

`params` is a pointer to a `params_t`, which is a struct of undefined nature. We can replace `params_t *params` with `void *params` and nothing will change from the perspective of the compiled code. But using `params_t *params` perhaps makes the code somewhat more readable.

I don't like to call `params` an *opaque pointer*, because that term is connected with concepts of information hiding and encapsulation. Is there a better term for `params` or `params_t`? Here, `params_t` simply helps to make the function somewhat flexible. I'm going to write in a documentation about a function like this, but I'm not sure what the best way to describe `params_t` is. I was wondering if there is a common term for such types/variables.

Comment: The right way to do this is with a `union`.

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449181)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks for the information. I was inspired by Cairo graphics library here. The main type in Cairo is declared as `typedef struct _cairo cairo_t`. I'm writing a library. `params_t`, with some prefix standing for the name of the library (not included here), forms part of the API.

Comment: @Barmar, in the actual code `params_t` is used in the parameter list of all functions which require this kind of "flexibility" shown in the code snippet above. And in the event handler the number of different kinds of events is potentially large. If I implement it with a `union` I'll have a very long `union`, which isn't attractive to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure what the best way to describe `params_t` is.

The C language spec would describe `params_t` as an *incomplete type*.  You could be more specific and call it an incomplete structure type.  Inasmuch as you compare with `void *`, it may interest you that C also categorizes `void` as an incomplete type.

> I don't like to call `params` an *opaque pointer*, because that term is connected with concepts of information hiding and encapsulation.

Suit yourself, but you're using exactly the same language features that are used to present and manipulate opaque types, and the function indeed doesn't know from the type itself what the members are.  If the shoe fits ....

Reaching beyond conventional C language terminology, you might call `params_t` an *abstract* type, making `params` a pointer to an abstract type.  I imagine that most C programmers would understand what you meant by that, especially in combination with satisfactory documentation for `event`.

> I was wondering if there is a common term for such types/variables.

No, not in C context.  But the term "abstract" is used in C++, Java, and some other OO languages for types that have conceptual similarity to your `params_t`.

Another term that you might draw from that arena would be "polymorphic". That matches your usage even better, but it has strong OO connotations that you might prefer to avoid (I would).

Comment: The only answer that dealt with the question! The other answers, though helpful, tried to improve the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what's already been said, you could consider getting rid of this whole "old-school" type-generic programming in favour of modern type-generic programming:

```
typedef struct {int i; int j;} params_event1_t;
typedef struct {int i; float f;} params_event2_t;

void event_handler1(params_event1_t* params) { /* ... */ }
void event_handler2(params_event2_t* params) { /* ... */ }

#define event_handler (param)                \
  _Generic((param)),                         \
           params_event1_t*: event_handler1, \
           params_event2_t*: event_handler2) (param)
```

This is type safe, resolved at compile-time and does not come with bad practices such as dirty casting or `void` pointers. No need for the `enum`, no need to implement some run-time type detection with a bunch of branches, no need to handle multiple unrelated things in the same function etc etc.

Unhandled events can get spotted at compile-time, alternatively you can add a `default` which calls an "unhandled event" function or assert.

Comment: Very interesting, though I can't use this for some reasons. Is this a feature of standardized C, like C11?

Comment: @apadana Yes, so this has been ISO C for 12 years by now.

Comment: I hadn't seen this before. I can't use this mainly because the event handler, in my case, is set by the user of the library I'm writing. And the number of different kinds of events is large.

Comment: @apadana You should seriously enforce a unified function API then, such as `typedef void event_handler_t (void*)` (and yeah now we're back to void pointers, yikes). But then you can create jump tables etc: `event_handler_t* const event [] = { [EVENT1]=event_handler1, [EVENT2]=event_handler2 };` and so on. Usage: `event[EVENT1](params)`

Answer (score 1):

Not a very good method. But first of all even your example code needs to have the correct syntax.

Use unions.

```
typedef enum {EVENT1, EVENT2} event_t;

typedef union
{
    struct {int i; int j;} params_event1;
    struct {int i; float f;} params_event2;
}params_t;

void event_handler(event_t event, params_t *params)
{
    switch(event)
    {
        case EVENT1:
            printf("%d %d\n", params -> params_event1.i, params -> params_event1.j);
            break;
        case EVENT2:
            printf("%d %f\n", params -> params_event2.i, params -> params_event2.j);
            break;
        
        /* .... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In the actual code `params_t` is used in the parameter list of all functions which require this kind of "flexibility" shown in the code snippet above. And in the event handler the number of different kinds of events is potentially large. If I implement it with a `union` I'll have a very long `union`, which isn't attractive to me.

Comment: I don't know. I should think again about it.

Answer (score 1):

> We can replace `params_t *params` with `void *params` and nothing will change from the perspective of the compiled code...

In that case, I think *opaque pointer* fits the bill.

I find those a bit risky. If someone gets it wrong, you will suddenly have an opaque pointer pointing at an element of the wrong type. I like hiding them in a `struct` which can then be passed around *by-value* and you'll get a nice compiletime error if someone gets it wrong. You could call this type a (params) *handle*.

```c
typedef enum { EVENT1, EVENT2, EVENT3 } event_t;

typedef struct { void *p; } params_t;             // void* hidden inside
typedef struct { int i; int j; } params_event1_t;
typedef struct { int i; float f; } params_event2_t;
typedef struct { char bigbuf[1024 * 1024 * 1024]; } params_event3_t;

// this will not accept "params" of the wrong type:
void event_handler(event_t event, params_t params) {
    switch (event) {
        case EVENT1: {
            params_event1_t *p = params.p;
            //...
            break;
        }
        case EVENT2: {
            params_event2_t *p = params.p;
            //...
            break;
        }
        case EVENT3: {
            params_event3_t *p = params.p;
            //...
            break;
        }
        default:
            LOG("Unhandled event");
            exit(1);
    }
}
```