# How to delete node from Binary Search Tree when it has 2 children

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am creating my first Tree ever. It seems like I am stuck on how to remove a node from the tree when it has 2 children. At the moment I am trying to:

- find the inorder successor (leftmost child of right child)
- replace the node to be deleted with it
- then point the successor to the right child that the previous node was pointing to

But when I try to print the tree after deleting a node, it gets stuck in a loop, and eventually causes a stack overflow.

```
void _rm_node(Node **n, int i)
{
    if (*n == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (i < (*n)->index)
    {
        _rm_node(&(*n)->left, i);
    }
    else if (i > (*n)->index)
    {
        _rm_node(&(*n)->right, i);
    }
    else
    {
        // no children
        if ((*n)->left == NULL && (*n)->right == NULL)
        {
            free(*n);
            *n = NULL;
        }
        //only left child
        else if ((*n)->left && (*n)->right == NULL)
        {
            Node *tmp = *n;
            *n = (*n)->left;
            free(tmp);
        }
        //only right child
        else if ((*n)->left == NULL && (*n)->right)
        {
            Node *tmp = *n;
            *n = (*n)->right;
            free(tmp);
        }
        else
        //2 children, replace n with inorder successor
        //right tree's leftmost/lowest index
        {
            Node *tmp = *n;
            Node *successor = (*n)->right;
            while (successor->left)
            {
                successor = successor->left;
            }

            *n = successor;
            (*n)->left = tmp->left;
            if (tmp->right->index != successor->index)
            {
                (*n)->right = tmp->right;
            }
            else
            {
                (*n)->right = NULL;
            }
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

```
void PrintTree(Node *t)
{
    if (t == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    printf("tree %d\n", t->index);
    PrintTree(t->left);
    PrintTree(t->right);
}
```

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449181)

Comment: I don't quite get what that bit with `index` is about, but the problem is probably that you don't clear the pointer from the original parent of the `successor` that you move up to become the new local root.

Comment: If you’re referring to ‘ if (tmp->right->index != successor->index)’ - then what I’m trying to do is only point ‘n’ to a different node, i.e. a node that has a different index. Are you saying that the parent of the successor should become a NULL pointer?

Comment: Maybe you should look at AVL trees or Red-Black (RB) trees. They already handle deletions. IIRC, AVL are faster at retrieval if not too many subsequent adds and deletes are done. Generally, RB are more useful (linux kernel uses them). Side note: go to my profile and see my avatar--I've _always_ been here ;-)

Comment: I’ve already started to look at AVL trees, but I am not going to move onto them until I can handle a BST without any rotation

Comment: Since you don't seem to be concerned about maintaining "balance" yet, an easy solution would be to recursively replace the payload of the _node-to-be-removed_ with the payload of one of the twin offspring. Repeat until encountering a node with 0 or 1 child nodes. (Ultimately, the node to delete will be a leaf node.) Easy, and likely to complete within very few recursions. Can be improved upon, too. Get something working and tested. It can supply your "reference check" when you move on to coding manipulations of a "balanced BST"...

Comment: The first bullet item needs to be a function that, given a pointer to the right child, returns a pointer to the leftmost child. It should change absolutely nothing while performing that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need update the parent `prev` of the `successor` to `successor->right`.  There are two cases:

   (a) The parent `prev` of `successor` is the node that we are overwriting so we need to update it's *right* pointer.  Your code does this correctly with `*n = successor;` but `(*n)->right = NULL;` is essentially a no-op.

   (b) Otherwise we need to update `prev`'s *left* pointer `prev->left = successor->right` which your code never does. `(*n)->right = tmp->right;` reverts the right pointer that `*n = successor;` incorrectly changed.
2. `*n = successor` is a little heavy handed as you only need to overwrite the `index`, and in case (a) the right pointer.
3. You use index values to determine if you are in case (a) and (b) which is ok if index values are unique.  Changed it to use the address of node instead which would work with duplicate index values, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    int index;
} Node;

Node *BuildTree(size_t n, int indices[n]);
void RemoveNode(Node **n, int i);

void PrintTree(Node *n) {
    if(!n) return;
    printf("tree %d\n", n->index);
    PrintTree(n->left);
    PrintTree(n->right);
}

void RemoveNode(Node **n, int i) {
    if (*n == NULL)
        return;
    if (i < (*n)->index) {
        RemoveNode(&(*n)->left, i);
        return;
    }
    if (i > (*n)->index) {
        RemoveNode(&(*n)->right, i);
    } else {
        // no children
        if ((*n)->left == NULL && (*n)->right == NULL)
        {
            free(*n);
            *n = NULL;
        }
        //only left child
        else if ((*n)->left && (*n)->right == NULL)
        {
            Node *tmp = *n;
            *n = (*n)->left;
            free(tmp);
        }
        //only right child
        else if ((*n)->left == NULL && (*n)->right)
        {
            Node *tmp = *n;
            *n = (*n)->right;
            free(tmp);
        }
        else
        {
            //2 children, replace n with inorder successor
            //right tree's leftmost/lowest index
            Node *prev = *n;
            Node *successor = (*n)->right;
            for(; successor->left; prev = successor, successor = successor->left);
            (*n)->index = successor->index;
            if(prev == *n)
                prev->right = successor->right;
            else
                prev->left = successor->right;
            free(successor);
        }
    }
}

Node *InsertNode(Node *root, int index) {
    Node *n = calloc(1, sizeof *n);
    n->index = index;
    Node **p = &root;
    while(*p) {
        if(index <= (*p)->index)
            p = &(*p)->left;
        else
            p = &(*p)->right;
    }
    *p = n;
    return root;
}

Node *BuildTree(size_t n, int indices[n]) {
    if(!n) return NULL;
    Node *t = NULL;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        t = InsertNode(t, indices[i]);
    return t;
}

void test(size_t n, int *indices) {
    Node *t = BuildTree(n, indices);
    printf("Before:\n\n");
    PrintTree(t);
    RemoveNode(&t, 6);
    printf("\nAfter:\n\n");
    PrintTree(t);
}

int main(void) {
    test(5, (int []) {10, 6, 2, 7, 9}); // a
    putchar('\n');
    test(6, (int []) {10, 6, 2, 8, 7, 9}); // b
}
```

and matching output:

```
Before:

tree 10
tree 6
tree 2
tree 7
tree 9

After:

tree 10
tree 7
tree 2
tree 9

Before:

tree 10
tree 6
tree 2
tree 8
tree 7
tree 9

After:

tree 10
tree 7
tree 2
tree 8
tree 9
```