# typedef struct clarification

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Can anyone explain me what is the difference between this:

```
typedef struct{
 char a[10];
 int b;
 char c[8];
 ...
}test;
```

and this:

```
typedef struct test{
 char a[10];
 int b;
 char c[8];
 ...
}test;
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C Typedef and Struct Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110944/c-typedef-and-struct-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef struct{
 char a[10];
 int b;
 char c[8];
 ...
}test;
```

The above defines an anonymous struct and immediately `typedef`s it to the type alias `test`.

```
typedef struct test{
 char a[10];
 int b;
 char c[8];
 ...
}test;
```

This however, creates a struct named `struct test` as well as adding a `typedef` for it.

In the first case, you will not be able to forward declare the `struct` if you need to.
There's also a [philosophy](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html) (which I happen to agree with to a point), that `typedef`ing all structures by default makes code less readable, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

Having "test" in two different places is a bit confusing. I usually write code like this:

```
typedef struct test_s {
    ...
} test;
```

Now I can either use type `struct test_s` or just `test`. While `test` alone is usually enough (and you don't need `test_s` in this case), you can't forward-declare pointer to it:

```
// test *pointer; // this won't work
struct test_s *pointer; // works fine

typedef struct test_s {
    ...
} test;
```

Comment: Names ending in `_t` are reserved by the standard. You might want to make it just `typedef struct test_s { ... } test_s;`. I don't think there's much value in having the typedefed name different from the struct tag.

Comment: Good to know. Will not use `_t` from now on. Difference is just for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

With the first version you can only declare:

```
test t;
```

With the second versijon you can choose between:

```
struct test t;
test t;
```

Answer (score -3):

**Short answer:** They're the same (in your code)

**Long answer:** Why put `test` between `typedef struct` and `{`? Is that pointless?

This (struct name `test`) is pointless in your code

In this code however, it's not:

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node * next;
} head;
```

Comment: There are differences and the latter is not valid.

Comment: @Olaf Oh, my bad, I missed `struct`

Comment: They are still not the same!

Comment: @Olaf they're both making the same struct, aren't they?

Comment: What do you mean with "make"? The standard does not use this term.

Comment: @Olaf What about "declare"?. Seriously though, "make" is a general verb in English, why must you bother about it?

Comment: Because when it comes to language-details, onme should be precise. "make" is very unspecific. The standard defines a lot of terms explicitly for this reason. Use them!

Comment: OK. So I mean "declare". Now, please tell me what do you mean by "same" and "different" in C standard so I can see your point.

Comment: It was not be using "the same", but you. So it would be you to define it. "different" OTOH has clear semantics.

Comment: The types are not the same because one of them has a tag and the other one doesn't.