# I cannot typedef a pointer to structure that has already been typedef-ed

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, typedef

I am a bit comfused about the row of these declarations. I want to make a linked-list for my program but for some reason it keeps putting error when I try to compile it. Basically this will be my main node model and I also have another struct after it (WITHOUT TYPEDEF) for my list. Which compiles just fine. I don't know what's wrong.

I have already tried to put the typedef over the struct student.

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int id;
    node next;

}student;

typedef student* node;

typedef struct listR* list;

struct listR
{
    node head,tail;
    int size;

};
```

error:
unknown type name 'node'
warning:
initialization make pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: On which line is the "unknown type name `node`" reported? Is it perhaps the line in `student` which is using `node` before it's been defined?

Comment: Watch the difference between listR and student,
On struct listR I don't have any error

Comment: In line 14 which is node next yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know what a node is, because you create the node type after creating the structure.

You can do either :

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
  char name[50];
  int id;
  node* next;
};
```

To tell the compiler what a node is,

Or

```
typedef struct node {
    char name[50];
    int id;
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

Comment: Both your ways in some way solved the problem!
but I also did that and worked:
typedef struct student * node;

typedef struct student{
    char name[50];
    int id;
    node next;
}

Comment: My solution was generic. Glad it helped. Your last solution (in the comment above) works because you prototype your structure, like in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
struct Node
{
  struct Node *next;
  struct Node *prev;
};
```

But then I happen to be one of those who does not like typedeffing structs without a good reason. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54752982/6699433