# what is the use of using the typedef and what does it signifies?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

I came across the code and it was kind of strange to me I am unable to understand what it means.

```
typedef struct alpha *Abc;
```

this is where Abc is defined;

```
struct alpha{
     Abc s;//what does this mean
}
```

also some where in function it is used like this

```
Abc iAmFunc(Abc beta,int a){
       some thing is performed
       return variable of type Abc
}
```

I dont understand the purpose of doing this can anyone explain me!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Comment: it shines when you do function pointers, den it becomes more clear why it is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, this is for C and not C++. Maybe it's applicable for C++ too, but I don't know.

`typedef a b` makes `b` an alias for `a`

What `typedef struct alpha *Abc;` is to make `Abc` an alias for `struct alpha *`. After you have created this, these two are equivalent:

```
struct alpha *ptr;
Abc ptr;
```

There are a few different uses for this:

It reduces how much you need to write. You can skip the `struct` word for instance. Many would say that this is NOT a good reason to use typedef.

It can give a more descriptive name for certain things. Examples:

```
typedef char* string; // I would never use this. It's just an example.
typedef int[3] vector; // However, this is something I would consider.
```

It can make it easier to change the type for a large code base in certain situations. Suppose you have this code:

```
int16_t foo(int16_t a)
{
    int16_t b = a+1;
    for(int16_t = 0; i<b; i++) {
...
```

And later you realize that it would be a good idea to change to `int32_t` instead. If the code instead looked like this, you would only need to change one line:

```
typedef int16_t T
T foo(T a)
{
    T b = a+1;
    for(T = 0; i<b; i++) {
...
```

Be restrictive with typedefs. Often they just clutters the code and makes it harder to follow. Use them when they fill a purpose. Be especially restrictive with aliasing pointers. I only use them for function pointers and completely opaque objects. Same thing with structs and unions. IMHO, 99% of the typedefs I see in questions here at SO are not necessary and seems to be there just because people think that they should.

If you consider typedefing a struct, ask yourself if it would be good to anyone reading the code to know that a declaration is a struct. If yes, declare it with the `struct` keyword. Of course you could invent something like `typedef struct my_struct my_struct_s` but is it really worth the effort? I'd say no.

It can be worth noting that C has something that seems like a simple form of namespace. This means that this completely valid:

```
typedef struct mystruct mystruct;
struct mystruct a;
mystruct b;
```

So `mystruct` is an alias for `mystruct`. And this is what you should do, unless you have a good reason not to.

I once wrote a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54752982/6699433) and if that answer wasn't so heavily focused on just structs, I would have made this question a duplicate.

In comments below, I saw this example:

```
typedef unsigned short int int_16;
```

and this is a HORRIBLE example. First, `int_16` gives the impression that it is a signed type, which it is clearly not. Secondly, `short int` (and its unsigned counterpart) is guaranteed to have *at least* 16 bits, but `int_16` gives the impression that it have *exactly* 16 bits. Depending on what you want, there are a few good ones in the standard:

- `int16_t` and `uint16_t` - Exactly 16 bits
- `int_least16_t` and `uint_least16_t` - At least 16 bits
- `int_fast16_t` and `uint_fast16_t` - At least 16 bits, but hint to the compiler that you want the fastest type

Comment: i often see use of `#define` and  `typedef` even for like defining same data type differently like `unsigned short int` to `int_16` and that is cascadingly `typedef` to some `i_am _bool` and `i_am_atom` i mean why to use this?instead of directly writing `unsigned short int`

Comment: @Nurav Don't assume people know what they're doing ;)

Comment: actually my question was not to know about typedef instead i was like stuck why would some one make things so complicated

Comment: @Nurav If you read the link in the answer, you'll get some good uses for it.

Comment: `typedef int[3] vector;` is a syntax error. Should be `typedef int vector[3];`. Type names can be tricky.

Answer (score 3):

The typedef defines a pointer type to `struct alpha` with type name `Abc`. Because of this, `Abc s;` translates to `struct alpha *s;`

Comment: can you tell me reason of doing this

Comment: It's how you alias complicated or annoyingly long types to a shorter name. It's just part of the C standard.

Comment: Using a `typedef` is a convenience as @tadman said, to save you from typing long,complicated expressions over and over. You effectively define a new type with it which you can then use in the rest of your code .

Comment: `typedef` does not define a type. It defines an alias for a type. This difference matters for C’s rules about compatibility of types.

Answer (score 1):

I want to expand on this part of Klutt's excellent answer a bit:

> Be restrictive with typedefs. Often they just clutters the code and makes it harder to follow. Use them when they fill a purpose. Be especially restrictive with aliasing pointers. I only use them for function pointers and completely opaque objects.

What Klutt is talking about here is *abstraction* - hiding implementation details of a type from the person using it.  Think about the `FILE` type in the standard library (`stdio.h`) - it is almost always a `typedef` name for a reasonably complex `struct` type.

However, the standard library doesn't *just* create the `typedef` name, it also provides a set of functions to create and manipulate `FILE` objects for you.  You *never* manipulate the contents of a `FILE` object directly, you always use the `stdio` functions to interact with it.  The abstraction is *complete* in that you can do everything necessary with a `FILE` without having to know any details of its implementation.

Contrast that with something like

```
typedef struct coord { double lat, lon; } Coordinates;

Coordinates c;
c.lat = 20.0;
c.lon = 47.5;
...
printf( "Coordinates: {%f:%f}\n", c.lat, c.lon );
```

where all I've done is create the typedef name `Coordinates`.  In order to *use* an object of `Coordinates` type, you have to *know* that it's a `struct` type with two members of type `double` named `lat` and `lon`.  The abstraction is "leaky" - details of the implementation "leak" out to the programmer.

To create a proper abstraction, I would need to expose only the typedef name without exposing its implementation, *and* I would need to provide a set of functions to manipulate coordinate types:

```
// Coord.h

/**
 * Forward declare the struct type; the type is incomplete at this point,
 * and will be completed in Coord.c
 */
struct coord;

/**
 * Create the typedef name - you can create typedef names for (and pointers 
 * to) incomplete types.
 */ 
typedef struct coord Coordinates; 

/**
 * Create a new Coordinates object and return a pointer to it.  Since the
 * Coordinates type is *incomplete* at this point, we cannot declare an
 * object of that type nor a function that returns an object of that type.
 * We can only declare things that are *pointers* to that type.  
 */
Coordinates *newCoord( double, double ); 

/**
 * Set the coordinates on an existing Coordinates object
 */
setCoord( Coordinates *, double, double ); 

/**
 * Compute the bearing from one set of coordinates to the other
 */
double bearing( const Coordinates *, const  Coordinates * );

/**
 * Return a string representation of the coordinate pair (suitable for
 * passing to printf and other display functions)
 */     
char *format( const Coordinates * );
```

etc., etc., etc.

This is why both Klutt and I recommend that you not use `typedef` *just* to rename things or avoid using the `struct` keyword.  Use it as part of creating a *complete* abstraction, or don't use it at all.

Also, **DO NOT HIDE POINTERS BEHIND `typedef`s!!!** It is a practice that *will* bite you in the ass at some point.  Pointer semantics are special and should not be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` is used to give something a new name. For example `typedef int ID`.
This makes a new type alias for int with the name ID, allowing you to use it. For example:

```
struct S
{
   ID id;
};
```

This is especially useful to make your code more readable, as having 4 ints in a class/struct ain't self explanatory.

In modern C++, we tend to step away from `typedef` and use `using` instead.

For example: `using ID = int;` this removes confusion when reading as it's obvious which is the new name and which the old. Though, it improves even more for pointers, like: `using IntPtr = int *;` iso `typedef int *IntPtr;` or function pointers: `using IntIntFunc = int(*)(int);` iso `typedef int(*IntIntFunc)(int);`

In C++, you can even take this a step further, and use it to make new strong types, see [Strong types for strong interfaces - fluentcpp.com](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/) for the details. (Also works with typedef)

The short version:

```
using ID = NamedType<int, struct IDTag>;
ID id = ID{0}; // OK
int width = 5;
id = width; // Compilation error
id = ID{width}; // OK again
```

This can prevent bugs because of typos where you accidentally mix types. A more useful place where this could make sense:

```
struct Rectangle { Height h; Width w; };
Rectangle r{5, 3}; // Doesn't compile
Rectangle r{Width{5}, Height{3}}; // Doesn't compile
Rectangle r{Height{3}, Width{5}}; // Does compile
```