# How to handle typedef datatypes in C (generally speaking)?

Tags: c, typedef

Basically the compiler complains of unknown type name 'Song_t' since the datatype definition happens after it is first referenced.

```
struct Cell { Song_t song;
            struct Cell *pnext;
};

typedef struct Song Song_t;
```

If I place the typedef before, it works.
Is it therefore generally advised to place typedefs at the very beginning of each file?

Comment: How can the compiler  know what is Somg_t in the structure definition?!

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your next question. Read also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), and study for inspiration the source code of *existing* C software on [github.com](http://github.com/) etc...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: This is not a debugging question and has no need of a minimal reproducible example. The question is sufficiently posed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: A compiler **could** examine the entire source file and, if possible, resolve types given that complete information of the file. It does not because C is largely designed to be compiled in one pass. But that is key information that a student may not yet know, so the rhetorical question you posed is an inadequate answer.

Comment: I wrote an answer regarding typedefs here. Maybe it could be considered a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54752982/6699433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it therefore generally advised to place typedefs at the very beginning of each file?

Not necessarily, and you could avoid `typedef` -s by coding

```
struct Cell { 
    struct Song song;
    struct Cell *pnext;
};
```

Of course, `struct Song` should be defined "before" (take into account the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)).

You could also code

```
typedef struct Song Song_t;
typedef struct Cell Cell_t;
```

and use later only `Song_t` etc. You do have to provide (later) a definition of `struct Song` (not just a forward declaration).
For details, read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website, and the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html).

Look for inspiration into the source code of the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/) or of a simple C compiler, such as [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/), or of the [GTK toolkit](https://gtk.org/). All these are coded (mostly) in C. Look also for examples on [github](https://github.com/). Study also the source code of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). It is a popular C compiler (and old versions of it -e.g. [GCC 4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/)- have been coded in C mostly).

Answer (score 3):

You can't refer to a typedef name before it's defined.

Either move the typedef before the `struct Cell` definition, or use `struct Song` in the `struct Cell` definition.

Answer (score 0):

The C compiler parses the preprocessed code in a single pass from top to bottom.

That means that any object or type must first be defined before it is used.

Comment: Not *exactly* true, because of the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Read the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The processor usually feeds tokens right into the parser. As such, it won't need a separate phase.

Comment: @PSKocik: It depends upon what you call a phase. In  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) that word does not even appear (and GCC is a C compiler). See [documentation of GCC internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/). AFAIK, GCC has several hundred optimization passes. See its file `gcc-10.*/gcc/passes.def`

Comment: C translation of course requires retrograde changes to previously scanned code, but most of that is handled by the linker. E.g., in `extern int x; int foo(void) { return x; } int x = 3;`, the instructions for `foo` cannot be fully resolved while `foo` is being scanned and `int x` has not been scanned. But even disregarding symbol resolution, there are aspects of C that require some look-ahead or retrograde work. For example, `switch` statements are not properly compiled, at least not well, without information about the `case` labels.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I should have used the word pass (i.e., a completed scan from beginning to end). I trust you understand what I mean.

Comment: And of course, optimizers throw all order out the window. Typical compilers build flow graphs and other data structures describing the program and then perform various transformations on them that have no bearing to source code order. A compiler with such processing cannot be said to operate solely in a single pass from top to bottom.

Comment: Again, GCC has more than two hundred [passes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Passes.html). Many of them operate on [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html)s, others on [RTL](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL.html). Your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) can add more passes

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch As Eric Postpischil has pointed out, the point is that C compilers *can* run in a single pass (with some backpatching). I think tinycc mostly does that. But yeah, the 1st sentence of this answer is indeed a bit misleading.

Comment: @PSkocik Updated to address parsing specifically.