# recursive type definitions in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, declaration, typedef

I'm trying to implement a linked list in C. I have tried the following implementations:

```c
// Attempt 1
typedef struct
{
  Node *next;
  Node *prev;
} Node;

// Attempt 2
typedef struct
{
  struct Node *next;
  struct Node *prev;
} Node;
```

The first version gives me the error: `unknown type name 'Node'`

The second compiles but gives warnings: `assignment to 'struct Node *' from incompatible pointer type 'Node *' {aka 'struct <anonymous> *'}` when I use it like this

```c
void link(Node * node) {
  node->next = (Node) {node, NULL}
}
```

Comment: `(Node) {node, NULL}` should be `(Node*)&{node, NULL}` since `next` is a pointer.

Comment: Change your `Attempt 2` to `typedef struct Node {...} Node;`

Comment: However, that would be invalid because the compound literal returns a pointer to local data.

Comment: What Eugene Sh. says or you can also do `typedef struct Node; struct Node { Node *next,*prev; };`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54752982/6699433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this declaration of an unnamed structure within the typedef declaration

```
typedef struct
{
  Node *next;
  Node *prev;
} Node;
```

the name `Node` used as a type specifier of data members `next` and `prev` is undeclared. So the compiler issues an error.

In this declaration of an unnamed structure in the typedef declaration

```
typedef struct
{
  struct Node *next;
  struct Node *prev;
} Node;
```

there are introduced the type specifier `struct Node` and the typedef name `Node` for the unnamed structure. They are different type specifiers. That is `Node` and `struct Node` are not the same specifiers.

What you need is the following

```
typedef struct Node
{
  struct Node *next;
  struct Node *prev;
} Node;
```

Now `Node` is an alias for the type specifier `struct Node`.

Pay attention to that this function definition

```
void link(Node * node) {
  node->next = (Node) {node, NULL}
}
```

does not make a sense and the compiler shall again issue an error.  The left operand of the assignment statement (where you forgot to place a semicolon)

```
  node->next = (Node) {node, NULL};
```

has the type `Node *` or `struct Node *` (if you will update the typedef declaration as it is shown above) while the right operand is a compound literal of the type `struct Node`. Moreover the compound literal has automatic storage duration and will not be alive after exiting the function.

So if you will even write

```
  node->next = &(Node) {node, NULL};
```

the pointer `node->next` will be invalid after exiting the function.

Comment: You can also declare the type first: `typedef struct Node Node;` and then use the new type in the structure definition: `struct Node { Node *next; Node *prev; };`