# Referencing an anonymous struct in itself

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, forward-declaration

```
typedef struct {
    //
} list;
```

vs

```
typedef struct list{
    //
} list;
```

I have read in another posts (such as [Using an anonymous struct vs a named struct with typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752861/using-an-anonymous-struct-vs-a-named-struct-with-typedef/54752982)) which says these two are almost equivalent and the only time when the later is required is when referencing the struct in itself.

However, the following compiles fine with clang and gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    struct list *next;
} list;

int main(){
 list l;
 return  0;
}
```

Above I have an anonymous struct referring to itself. How is this compiling?

Comment: `struct list` and `list` are different types . Struct tags have a different "namespace" to typedef names. You will encounter problems if you try to point `next` to a `list`

Comment: You are declaring `next` as a pointer to something called `struct list` that has nothing to do with the struct type currently being defined.  Note that it works just as "well" with `typedef struct { struct asdfasdf *next; } list;`

Comment: I see, so if I do use the later, then `struct list*` would be the same type as the outer `list`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters there is neither anonymous structure in your question. There are examples of unnamed structures.

The notion of the anonymous structure is defined in the C Standard the following way (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 13 **An unnamed member of structure type with no tag is called an
> anonymous structure;** an unnamed member of union type with no tag is
> called an anonymous union. The members of an anonymous structure or
> union are considered to be members of the containing structure or
> union. This applies recursively if the containing structure or union
> is also anonymous.

As for this declaration

```
typedef struct {
    struct list *next;
} list;
```

then there are declared two different types: unnamed structure with the alias name `list` and an incomplete declaration of the type `struct list`. `list` and `struct list` are two different incompatible types.

For example if you will try this simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    struct list *next;
} list;

int main(void) 
{
    list lst1;
    list lst2;
    
    lst1.next = &lst2;
    
    return 0;
}
```

then the compiler will issue an error for this statement

```
lst1.next = &lst2;
```

saying that there is an assignment to ‘struct list *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘list *’.

Comment: I thought a struct without a name is called `anonymous`? what's the difference between unnamed and anonymous?

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to clarify, this is forward declaration correct? making pointer to a `struct list` (inside the struct) which doesn't exist yet?

Comment: @Dan Yes you may declare a pointer to an incomplete type.

Comment: which is specifically called forward declaration?

Comment: @Dan Yes, it may be considered as a forward declaration.