# C - Hiding implementation of a struct

Tags: c, struct

I've read in different posts that the implementation of struct can be hidden in C by doing the following:

**test.h:**

```
typedef struct SomeTest *SomeTest;
SomeTest make();
```

**test.c:**

```
#include "test.h"
typedef struct SomeTest {
    int data;
}*SomeTest;
```

What I wonder though:
Is the line:

```
typedef struct SomeTest *SomeTest;
```

really needed that way? Wouldn't it be sufficient to:

**test.h:**

```
   typedef struct SomeTest SomeTest;
   SomeTest *make();
```

**test.c:**

```
#include "test.h"
struct SomeTest {
    int data;
};
```

It's just that the line:

```
typedef struct SomeTest *SomeTest;
```

gives me headaches sometimes,...and it hides the fact that "SomeTest" is a pointer...

Comment: Check out this post: [How can I hide the declaration of a struct in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154709/how-can-i-hide-the-declaration-of-a-struct-in-c)

Comment: Yes, looks more the way I would do it, but still,...why do I see `typedef struct SomeTest *SomeTest` that often? It's more a question of style I guess?

Comment: @inzanez It gives as all hedache and sadly, it's frequently used.

Comment: @iharob: thanks, that's reassuring,...!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a matter of coding style. Many people, me including, are really confused when a pointer is hidden behind a `typedef`. Adding the little `*` at each occurrence is not really a big deal, but helps a lot to clarify things for the occasional reader.

The other aspect of that `typedef` is really bad: using the same identifier for things (the `struct` tag and the `typedef`ed name) that are of different type (one a `struct` and the other a pointer) should not be allowed and really confuses. This is really bad, bad style and should never pass any code review.