# What is the difference when using typdef when declaring a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why should we typedef a struct so often in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c)
>   [Difference between ‘struct’ and ‘typedef struct’ in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

What is the difference between the following type declarations?

```
struct Person
{
    int age;
};


typedef struct 
{
    int age;
}Person;
```

I understand that

```
struct 
{
    int age;
}Person;
```

Creates and instance of an unnamed struct called person, where

```
struct Person
{
    int age;
};
```

declares a type called person, but not an instance. But I still dont get what the typedef does.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Comment: and at least half a dozen other questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's the same as in C, typedef creates an alias of a type... in your first case, the name of the type is "`struct Person`", while in the second case is just "`Person`".

Usually, when you have to declare self referencing structures (like lists), you use both, because the typedef has not effect until the structure is defined (unless you make a forward declaration), for example:

```
typedef struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
} TNode, *PTNode;
```

so now you can declare variables of the same type in the following ways:

```
struct node *node1;
TNode *node2;
PTNode node3;
```

the three variables above are the same, pointers to the node structure.

Comment: This was the understanding I got from the wikipedia page.

Comment: In C++ (which is what the question was about), this is not the same as in C.

Comment: @sbi I cannot see how it differs from C to C++... maybe you'll be kind to explain it to us.

Comment: @fortran: See my answer. In C++, `struct X {}` can be referred to as `X` (while in C, it must be referred to as `struct X`). So in C++, there is no need for the `typedef` at all. Except when you write headers that are supposed to be parsed by a C compiler, too, this is just a C-ism that people use without thinking (or knowing) about.

Answer (score 2):

In C, structs live in their own name space, so you have to write `struct Person` if you want to use the struct's type name. The `typedef` eliminates the need for that prefix.

In C++, structs live in the same name space as everything else, so there's no need to do this. It's usually seen as an unnecessary C-ism.

Answer (score 0):

c-compatibility
essentially same in c++, there for legacy c-code

not sure about referring to static functions and typedefs in the unnamed struct when you do the definition this way - I never do.

Answer (score 0):

you can tell the difference when passing Person or struct Person to a function

If you defined

```
struct Person { ... };
```

You should pass it to a function explicitly stating that it is a struct

```
void foo(struct Person person) { ... }
```

On the other hand, if you defined

```
typedef struct Person { ... };
```

You must not state that it is a struct, since the keyword typedef allows you to actually define a data type, in this case Person and you pass it this way

```
void foo(Person person) { ... }
```

pretty much like any other data type

Hope this helps

Comment: You meant 

typedef struct { ... } Person;

right? Anyway, this is only so in C, not in C++.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ *typedefs* are synonyms for other types rather than distinct types. They are generally used for two purposes:

- Creating portable code where you abstract the platform specific away. On one platform you can have `typedef int int32` and on another platform `typedef long int32`. You would use `int32` throughout your code and when porting to the a new platform you would only have to modify the typedefs to match your requirements.
- Creating aliases for very complicated types. E.g. `typedef char const* const* cppchar`. Instead of writing `char const* const*` in your code you can now write `cppchar`.