# C structs don't define types?

Tags: c

I've just started learning C with a professional Java background and some (if no too much) C++ knowledge, and I was astonished that this doesn't work in C:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

Point p;

p.x = 0;
p.y = 0;
```

It seems that I have to declare `p` using `struct Point` as the type or using a `typedef`. Does this code works in C99? Or is this a "C++ thing"?

Comment: Declare p as `struct Point p;`. You can use typedefs but I would recommend you get into the practice of referring to your type as `struct Point`.

Comment: @PP: I second that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions/1675507#1675507

Comment: @PP Why? What wrong with the typedef in your eyes?

Comment: @Grumdrig: I've never advocated re-defining a language through typedefs. It makes code maintenance and reviews more difficult. If something is a struct, say so. There, of course, are situations whereby different int types are better served as typedefs. But I don't believe there is often a good case for doing the same to structs. Again, this is anti-Google-Go philosophy whereby keywords are seen as evil and instead capitalisation is used to differentiate between public/private functions; but I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: @Grumdrig - it's a pain to add a const or const pointer "modifer" to a typedef that already has a const or even just a pointer in.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, it shouldn't work without a `typedef` in C99 either (as this is simply the way C works), but it does work in C++ as a `struct` in C++ is just a `class` with all members public by default.

Comment: Down-voted because this most definitely has worked since K&R C. There is a big difference between a `typedef` and a `struct` or `enum`.

Comment: Mikael is right, C++ does not require you to use struct while declaring types of the structure. Why was the answer down voted?

Comment: Ah, re-upvoting as misread the question/answer; technically Mikael is correct, a typedef is required if the struct typename is desired without the `struct` keyword beforehand. As a long-time user of C I stand by my recommendation that the type (struct) is explicitly stated.

Answer (score 5):

No, a struct do not define a new type. What you need is:

```
typedef struct {
   int x; int y;
} Point;
```

Now Point is new type you can use:

```
Point p;
p.x = 0; p.y = 0;
```

Comment: A struct does define a type. That's why after defining `struct Foo`, I can declare a variable `struct Foo a`.

Comment: Right; the point of confusion is that the struct *tag* does not serve as the type name by itself; it must be preceded by the `struct` keyword.

Comment: You're right, I should have been more precise.  A structure like "struct tag { ... };" does not set 'tag' as a new type. Of course you can use that tag to specify that a variable has that structure as in "struct tag var;".
It seemed to me that the OP was not clear on the role that the struct tag plays vs. the type one defines with typedef.

Answer (score 4):

`struct Point` **is the type** just like `union Foo` would be a type.  You can use `typedef` to alias it to another name - `typedef struct Point Point;`.

Answer (score 4):

In C there is no confusion between

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

and

```
union Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

which are two different types called `struct Point` and `union Point` respectively.

The C99 standard section 6.7.2.1 states:

> 6  Structure and union specifiers have
>   the same form. The keywords `struct` and
>   `union`  indicate that the type being
>   specified is, respectively, a
>   structure type or a union type.
>
> 7 The
>   presence of a struct-declaration-list
>   in a struct-or-union-specifier
>   declares a new type,   within a
>   translation unit.

So it most unequivocally declares a type. The syntax for type names in C is given in sections 6.7.6 and includes the *specifier-qualifier-list* from 6.7.2, which takes the form of `struct-or-union identifier`.

> Does this code works in C99? Or is this a "C++ thing"?

No, C99 does not decide to promote structure types over enum types and union types with the same name. It is a "C++ thing", as struct and classes are mostly the same thing in C++, and classes are important to C++.

Comment: Actually, I believe there is confusion, or at least there used to be - the tag namespace being shared between `struct`, `union`, and `enum`, and I've even heard some people suggest that it may be valid to declare `struct foo bar;` when `foo` was defined as a `union` but never as a `struct`. Not sure what the current state of affairs is, but it's a messy subject.

Answer (score 2):

So...

```
Point           a tag
struct Point    a type

typedef struct {
    . . .
} Point_t;

Point_t         a type
```

I often see a ***why?*** written between the lines. After all, it does seem perfectly reasonable to just say `Point x;`, so why can't you?

As it happens, early implementations of C established a separate *name space* for tags vs other identifiers.There are actually *4* name spaces<sup>1</sup>. Once the language was defined this way, it was then not possible to allow the struct tag to be used as a type because then all existing code with name collisions between *ordinary identifiers* and *tags* would be suddenly in error.

---

<sup>1. The 4 *name spaces* are:

-- label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);

-- the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any) of the keywords struct, union, or enum);

-- the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name
space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the
member via the . or -> operator);

-- all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as
enumeration constants)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work in C99, it is a C++ thing.  You have to either say `struct Point` or use a typedef in C.

Answer (score 1):

Structs are not types.  You can create a point from a struct as follows:

```
struct Point p;
p.x = 0;
p.y = 0;
```

If you want to use a struct as a type, you have to typedef it.  This works in both C and C++:

```
typedef struct _point {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;
```

Always give your struct a name though, if you have to forward declare it to be able to have pointers to a struct of the same type or circular dependencies.

Comment: structs are types. The name of the type defined by struct Point {} is "struct Point"

Answer (score 1):

In C, structs can have two kinds of names: a tag name, and a type name.  A tag name can only be used if it's prefixed with struct, like:

```
struct mytag { int a; }
struct mytag mystruct;
```

A typedef allows you to define both a tag name and a type name. The type name can be used without a struct prefix:

```
typedef struct mytag { int a; } mytype;
mytype mystruct; // No struct required
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way C works.  In C you have to say:

```
typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;
```

And then you'll have a type called `Point` that does what you want.

In C++ it's enough to define it the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make Point a type like :

```
typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;
```

This allows you to use `Point` as a type, or `struct Point`

I.e:

```
Point *p;

sizeof(struct Point);
```

Some people prefer to make the name of the structure different from the type being created, such as:

```
typedef struct _point {
       ...
} Point;
```

You'll run into both. The last example tells me that I should not use `struct _point`, its not meant to be exposed except as the type `Point`.

Comment: The last example tells you that behaviour is undefined by the C standard. Tag names (in fact all identifiers) beginning with an underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved. Of course, usually non-portable code is fine - if it passes the tests today then who cares if it will still work tomorrow, right? But why rely on _Point not being actually used by the current version of your current compiler, when you don't have to?

Comment: @Steve - absolutely correct. Never use a leading underscore followed by an uppercase letter (this is in paragraph 4 of section 6.10.8 for C99)

Comment: I was giving examples based on the OP's example, using his names, variables and types. I'll edit the answer, though.

Comment: Now you have the same problem if the typedef has file scope (in which case underscore followed by a lowercase letter is also reserved). It's OK in a function body, though. Initial underscores are pretty much best avoided, unless you're writing bits of the implementation (for instance if you're writing the standard headers to go with a compiler). The common portable forms I've seen are `typedef struct Point { ... } Point;` and `typedef struct Point_tag { ... } Point;`. The reason for "_tag" is that the identifier that comes after struct is in the so-called "tag namespace".