# Objective C - when should "typedef" precede "enum", and when should an enum be named?

Tags: objective-c, enums, typedef

In sample code, I have seen this:

```
typedef enum Ename { Bob, Mary, John} EmployeeName;
```

and this:

```
typedef enum {Bob, Mary, John} EmployeeName;
```

and this:

```
typedef enum {Bob, Mary, John};
```

but what compiled successfully for me was this:

```
enum {Bob, Mary, John};
```

I put that line in a .h file above the @interface line, and then when I #import that .h file into a different class's .m file, methods there can see the enum.

So, when are the other variants needed?

If I could name the enum something like EmployeeNames, and then, when I type "EmployeeNames" followed by a ".", it would be nice if a list pops up showing what the enum choices are.

Comment: You might also be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In C (and hence Objective C), an enum type has to be prefixed with `enum` every time you use it.

```
enum MyEnum enumVar;
```

By making a typedef:

```
typedef MyEnum MyEnumT;
```

You can write the shorter:

```
MyEnumT enumVar;
```

The alternative declarations declare the enum itself and the typedef in one declaration.

```
// gives the enum itself a name, as well as the typedef
typedef enum Ename { Bob, Mary, John} EmployeeName;

// leaves the enum anonymous, only gives a name to the typedef
typedef enum {Bob, Mary, John} EmployeeName;

// leaves both anonymous, so Bob, Mary and John are just names for values of an anonymous type
typedef enum {Bob, Mary, John};
```

Comment: These are all helpful answers. This idea of declaring a variable of the enumerated type is intriguing. Doing so, I suppose, limits the possible values of the variable. I have never used an enum like that in other languages. I just used the enum declaration itself as a holder of possible values. For example:
     If MyFish = FishSpecies.Mackeral Then...
or, as I type, I can get IntelliSense as follows:
    x = FishSpecies.Cod
                    Hallibut
                    Mackeral
etc. (Sorry I can't format this in a comment.) Can Xcode do that kind of IntelliSense with an enum, like VB?

Comment: @Scott - the problem is that in C the possible enum value names are merged into the global scope (or in C++, they go into the same namespace the enum type is declared in). So in fact `FishSpecies` doesn't contain anything called `Cod`. You just have to say `Cod`. In C++ its good practice to always declare enums nested in some class or namespace to avoid pollution of the global namespace. In C++1x there will be an enhanced enum variety where you'd write `FishSpecies::Cod`. And of course in C#, VB.NET (and Java 5 or later I think) you already get what you're familiar with.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Objective C stays faithful to plain ANSI C aside from the dynamic OO extensions which are very much segregated from the rest of the language. Totally different approach from C++ which aims also to be "a better C". Though the advantage is that you can combine the two languages and get Objective C++ (which is what I'd use if I dabbled in iPhone dev, as there's no GC on the iPhone, and C++ enables an essential workaround called smart pointers... look them up!)

Comment: As with structs, the following is ok too:
`typedef enum MyEnum MyEnum;`
Since they are in different namespaces, the tag and type name can be the same

Comment: Should we put the typedef enum inside the interface declaration, or outside? Im using Apple LLVM 4.0

Answer (score 4):

The names inside `enum { }` define the enumerated values. When you give it a name, you can use it as a type together with the keyword `enum`, e.g. `enum EmployeeName b = Bob;`. If you also `typedef` it, then you can drop the `enum` when you declare variables of that type, e.g. `EmployeeName b = Bob;` instead of the previous example.

Answer (score 0):

Your third example is the same as your last example - the `typedef` there is useless - GCC even gives a warning about that case:

```
warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
```

Your first and second example are also partly equivalent, in that they both give the enum type a name `EmployeeName`.  The first example also lets you use `enum Ename` interchangeably with `EmployeeName`; in the second example, `EmployeeName` is the only option.  The second example has to be written as you have - you can decompose the first example as follows:

```
enum Ename { Bob, Mary, John };
typedef enum Ename EmployeeName;
```

Maybe that helps clear things up?