# Is there a difference between these two stuct-related declarations?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have the following structure

```
typedef struct _LSHFunctionT 
{
    double *a;
    double b;
} LSHFunctionT, *PLSHFunctionT;
```

My question is; is there a difference between these two declarations

```
PLSHFunctionT myPointer1;
```

and

```
LSHFunctionT *myPointer2;
```

and if not, then why do people explicitly use two of them (LSHFunctionT and *PLSHFunctionT). Why not just use LSHFunctionT.

Does it go the same way for the following two declarations

```
PLSHFunctionT *myPointer3;
```

and

```
LSHFunctionT **myPointer3;
```

Comment: And to your question "why do people explicitly use two of them (LSHFunctionT and *PLSHFunctionT)", I think some people just find it "cleaner" to write `Pwhatever ptr` than `whatever* ptr`, because they don't like asterisks or something. ::shrug::

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct _LSHFunctionT 
{
    double *a;
    double b;
} LSHFunctionT, *PLSHFunctionT;
```

Yes, `PLSHFunctionT x;` is equal to `LSHFunctionT* x;`

And yes, `PLSHFunctionT* x;` is equal to `LSHFunctionT** x;`

The purpose of `typedef` is to assign new names to existing types. You can define `typedef int lol;` and declare variable `lol i;`, but compiler will consider it `int` anyway.

You should also check these questions:
[When should I use typedef in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/516237/1168156)
[Why should structure names have a typedef?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2605681/1168156)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are identical.

One good reason to define a pointer type is for complicated expressions. If for example you have a function that takes a reference to a pointer, which do you find easier to understand?

```
void foo(PLSHFunctionT & ref);

void foo(LSHFunctionT * (&ref));
```

I'm not even sure I got the syntax correct for the second one!

Comment: `void foo(LSHFunctionT * & ref)` is fine. No need to use extra-braces.

Comment: @Nawaz, thanks. But you see my point - it's hard to remember if it's not something you do every day. And I did have it incorrect at first but I did a quick edit.

Comment: Yup. Its easy to make mistake. One may try `void foo(LSHFunctionT & * ref)` which is a compilation error. But it is equally possible when you use `typedef`. e.g `typedef T& RT;void foo(RT * ptr)` which is compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in emphasis. Generally not explicitly writing the * may indicate that the PLSHFunctionT is designed to be used as a handle (without knowing/accessing structure elements ). If * is explicitly written, as in LSHFunctionT *myPointer, it might indicate an array or a structure that is to be used to access the values.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between the two on the surface. However, with the pointer typedef there's no way to declare it as pointer-to-const, just const-pointer-to-non-const.

For example you can say

`const LSHFunctionT* const_ptr;` but `const PLSHFunctionT const_ptr2;` makes the pointer const, NOT the pointee.

Finally note that in C++ the whole thing is of questionable legality because names starting with `_<capital>` are reserved for the implementation, and that typedefs are almost never used in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

I seem there is no difference. There are different programming styles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They are exactly same, even in the second case.

I personally prefer using `*` explicitly if I want to declare a pointer. It makes the code readable, in most cases. Usage of `typedef` of pointer-type reduces readability usually, though sometimes it may increases readability especially when you work with, say, Windows API.

Comment: Ah yes, the Windows API, with its PSTR, LPSTR, PCSTR, LPCSTR, LPCTSTR, LPUTSTR, LPCUTSTR etcetera. Lovely.

Answer (score 0):

Those declarations are the same. The pointer-typedef approach improves code readability in some cases. One could argue that this:

```
PLSHFunctionT calls[];
```

is easier to read than this:

```
LSHFunctionT *calls[];
```