# struct and typedef in C versus C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, typedef

I am currently using a C++ IDE for something that will need to work on C, and wanted to make sure that I won't have problems with this later on. After making the struct below:

```
typedef struct test {
   int a;
   int b;
};
```

I then create an instance of it using 
`test my_test;` then stuff like `my_test.a = 5`, etc... and this works fine in my VStudio C++.
Is this going to work on `gcc` later on?

I read the related questions that popped up (I see I am not the first person with this kind of  question, either) but no one seemed to use the way I did.

In fact, what is the difference between `typedef struct {//stuff} test;` and my version?

Comment: You can compile your program by opening command prompt and typing: `gcc FilePath/foo.c`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typedef struct vs struct definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions) I wrote an extensive answer on the differences and the concrete and actual meaning of each of those two constructs in C and C++ as an answer to the linked question. Read it for details not available in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference between:

```
struct Name {};
```

And

```
typedef struct Name {} Name;
```

Is that, in C, you need to use:

```
struct Name instance_name;
```

With the former, whereas with the latter you may do:

```
Name instance_name;
```

In C++, it is not necessary to repeat the `struct` keyword in either case. Note that your example in which you create a typedef with no name (i.e. `typedef struct Name{};`) is non-standard AFAIK (if you use the keyword `typedef`, then you need to supply an alias to which to typedef that name).

As for the last variation:

```
typedef struct { /* ... */ } Name;
```

The code above creates an unnamed struct that is aliased to Name. You would use such a struct just the same way you would with `typedef struct Name { /* ... */ } Name;`, however compilers often emit the name of the struct (not the alias), and so you may get better error messages involving the struct if you give it a name and typedef that as opposed to typedef'ing an anonymous struct.

Comment: I just noticed that "Warning 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'test' when no variable is declared" is what I get when I do things the way I wrote in my original code snippet. Which begs the question what does the thing I wrote even do?

Comment: @user472875: Nothing.  It's like writing "typedef int;".  Or like writing a definition in a dictionary without giving the word that means that thing.

Answer (score 22):

```
typedef struct THIS_IS_A_TAG
{
    int a;
    int b;
} THIS_IS_A_TYPEDEF;

THIS_IS_A_TYPEDEF object1;     // declare an object.       C:Ok,     C++:Ok
struct THIS_IS_A_TAG object2;  // declare another object.  C:Ok,     C++:Ok
THIS_IS_A_TAG object3;         // declare another object.  C:Not Ok, C++:Ok
```

The reason for the typedef is because C programmers would like to be able to do that third thing, but they can't.

Answer (score 8):

In both C and C++, the example construct is modestly pointless:

```
typedef struct test {
   int a;
   int b;
};
```

In C, this says there is a type `struct test` with the two integers as content.  If there was a name between the close brace '`}`' and the semi-colon '`;`', then you would get some benefit from the keyword `typedef`; as it stands, the keyword `typedef` is redundant, and (if set fussy enough), GCC will warn you about it.

In C++, this says there is a type `struct test`; further, in C++, it creates a type `test` too (which does not happen in C).  The keyword `typedef` can still be left out and the same result will be achieved.

The syntax is legal; it is not useful, that's all.  The keyword `typedef` can be omitted without changing the program's meaning in the slightest.

You can do:

```
typedef struct test {
   int a;
   int b;
} test;
```

Now, in both C and C++, you have a type `struct test` and an alias for it `test`.