# typedef struct elt *Stack; why is there a * here

Tags: c++, c, pointers, data-structures, stack

This is the full code of an implementation of Stack using Linked Lists. It's from Data Structures notes for Yale University by James Aspnes(is it any good?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct elt {
    struct elt *next;
    int value;
};

/* 
 * We could make a struct for this,
 * but it would have only one component,
 * so this is quicker.
 */
typedef struct elt *Stack;

#define STACK_EMPTY (0)

/* push a new value onto top of stack */
void
stackPush(Stack *s, int value)
{
    struct elt *e;

    e = malloc(sizeof(struct elt));
    assert(e);

    e->value = value;
    e->next = *s;
    *s = e;
}

int
stackEmpty(const Stack *s)
{
    return (*s == 0);
}

int
stackPop(Stack *s)
{
    int ret;
    struct elt *e;

    assert(!stackEmpty(s));

    ret = (*s)->value;

    /* patch out first element */
    e = *s;
    *s = e->next;

    free(e);

    return ret;
}

/* print contents of stack on a single line */
void
stackPrint(const Stack *s)
{
    struct elt *e;

    for(e = *s; e != 0; e = e->next) {
        printf("%d ", e->value);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    Stack s;

    s = STACK_EMPTY;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("push %d\n", i);
        stackPush(&s, i);
        stackPrint(&s);
    }

    while(!stackEmpty(&s)) {
        printf("pop gets %d\n", stackPop(&s));
        stackPrint(&s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can understand most of the code. But I can't wrap my head around this part 
`typedef struct elt *Stack;`

Why is there a * before Stack and what does it mean?

I'm finding a concepts of pointers, especially in return types of functions hard to grasp.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a tutoring site. The concept of pointers is pretty broad and should be studied using dedicated resources.

Comment: This is `C` code, not C++.  This line: `e = malloc(sizeof(struct elt));` would not compile as C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: What in the code prevents the code from being compiled as C++?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The return value of `malloc` not being casted.  A cast is required for C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know it's C. I tagged both since both are similar. My bad.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Sorry man. Any good resource on that?

Comment: @user3600999 try this: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Thanks dude. I'll check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can understand most of the code. But I can't wrap my head around
>   this part  typedef struct elt *Stack;

That is using typedef*. That just means when you write

```
Stack x;
```

in your code it means:

```
struct elt * x;
```

If you however use

```
Stack *s;
```

in your code it will mean:

```
struct elt ** s;
```

> I'm finding a concepts of pointers, especially in return types of
>   functions hard to grasp. Thanks in advance.

Then I recommend you first understand pointers and pointers to pointers well before proceeding with that code.

---

*<sub>I think there are some subtle differences with typedefs in C and C++: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082972/struct-and-typedef-in-c-versus-c)</sub>

Comment: Thanks man. Can you tell me if there's a difference between int *foo & int *(foo)?

Comment: @user3600999 Is foo a variable there? No there should be not: https://ideone.com/mgjfPW

Comment: No. A function. Sorry, I wasn't clear on that. BTW, why does he use a `struct elt *e;` instead of just `Stack e` inside StackPush and other functions

Comment: @user3600999 He just uses for comfort to type less ** stars. you need to show full code snippet of those function definitions

Answer (score 1):

> I'm finding a concepts of pointers, especially in return types of functions hard to grasp. Thanks in advance.

That's a bit more than can be covered here; find yourself a good tutorial (if such a thing exists) and work from there.  However, here are some things to remember:

- In a pointer declaration, the `*` operator is always bound to the *declarator*, not the type specifier.  For example, the declaration

  ```
  int* x, y, z;
  ```

  is *parsed* as

  ```
  int (*x), y, z;
  ```

  IOW, only `x` is declared as a pointer.  If you want to declare `y` and `z` as pointers as well, you would have to write

  ```
  int *x, *y, *z;
  ```

  The unary `*` and `&` operators have lower precedence than postfix operators like `[]`, `()`, and member selection operators, so:

  ```
  T *x[N];   // declares x as an N-element array of pointers to T
  T (*x)[N]; // declares x as a pointer to an N-element array of T
  T *f();    // declares f as a function returning pointer to T
  T (*f)();  // declares f as a pointer to a function returning T

  *a.b  == *(a.b)    // dereferences a.b
  *a->b == *(a->b)   // dereferences a->b
  &a.b  == &(a.b)    // takes the address of a.b
  &a->b == &(a->b)   // takes the address of a->b
  a->b  == (*a).b    // dereferences a, then accesses b
  ```

  There is no single pointer type; instead, there are many different pointer types, and most are not *compatible* with each other; if a function is expecting an argument of type `int *`, it will complain if you pass it something of type `int **` (or `int (*)[N]`, or `int **`, or `float *`, etc.)  The `void *` type is a "generic" pointer type, but you cannot work with it directly (you can't dereference a `void *`, nor can you do pointer arithmetic on it).  In C, you can assign `void *` values to any pointer object and vice versa without a cast; C++ requires a cast for `all` pointer type conversions.

  ***ARRAYS ARE NOT POINTERS***.  The array subscript operation is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic:

  ```
  a[i] == *(a + i);
  ```

  We offset `i` elements (**not bytes**) from the address `a` and dereference the result.  But, if arrays are not pointers, how does this work?  

  Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  Thus, when we write `a[i]`, the array expression `a` is converted to a pointer type, and we offset from that pointer.  Note that the *object* `a` is not converted; it is always an array object.